# How do I get a timestamp in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, date-arithmetic

I want a single number that represents the current date and time, like a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 6033, accepted):

#### Timestamp in milliseconds

To get the number of milliseconds since [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), call [`Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now):

```
Date.now()
```

Alternatively, use the unary operator `+` to call [`Date.prototype.valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf):

```
+ new Date()
```

Alternatively, call [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) directly:

```
new Date().valueOf()
```

To support IE8 and earlier (see [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Date.now)), create a *shim* for `Date.now`:

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
}
```

Alternatively, call [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) directly:

```
new Date().getTime()
```

---

#### Timestamp in seconds

To get the number of seconds since [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), i.e. *Unix timestamp*:

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

Alternatively, using bitwise-or to floor is slightly faster, but also less readable and may break in the future (see explanations [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487977/using-bitwise-or-0-to-floor-a-number), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11446757/1519836)):

```
Date.now() / 1000 | 0
```

---

#### Timestamp in milliseconds (higher resolution)

Use [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now):

```js
var isPerformanceSupported = (
    window.performance &&
    window.performance.now &&
    window.performance.timing &&
    window.performance.timing.navigationStart
);

var timeStampInMs = (
    isPerformanceSupported ?
    window.performance.now() +
    window.performance.timing.navigationStart :
    Date.now()
);

console.log(timeStampInMs, Date.now());
```

Comment: In case you wonder about the logic of `plus` sign is: `+` is used as `toInt()` where it will neglect all the characters and return only numbers

Comment: Or use an online tool: https://magictools.dev/#!/tools/timestamp-to-date

Answer (score 634):

I like this, because it is small:

```
+new Date
```

I also like this, because it is just as short and is compatible with modern browsers, and over 500 people voted that it is better:

```
Date.now()
```

Comment: @Billy As I recall it, I computed the timestamp in the two suggested solutions 1M times each, and calculated the average runtime. I ran it in Firefox and Chrome, with getTime being faster in both browsers. That said, even if it were (marginally) slower I'd choose `new Date().getTime()`. Luckily for me, the faster solution is already the legible solution!

Comment: Agreed with @FabrícioMatté.  Unary operator behavior may not be rudimentary, but if you haven't brushed up on it, don't expect to be able to function effectively in a lot of teams.

Comment: @Niklaus That's because you're concatenating it to another string. In that case, `new Date().toString()` is called.

Comment: + is unary mathmatic in this case.  typeof (+new Date()) evaluates to "number".  Basically it's shorthand for new Date().valueOf() -- without the javascript function call.  But don't write it this way, it looks like a typo.

Comment: @Niklaus in that case you would need another plus to act as the unary operator: `'NEW-' + +new Date`

Comment: The +new Date does not seem to work in Chrome 52, if the desired effect is to generate an integer. I am confident it worked on older Chromes.

Comment: @MarcusJohansson people should be using `Date.now()` if they are using a newer browser like Chrome. I tried this in Chrome 52 and Chrome Canary 55 and `+new Date` still worked.

Comment: @FelixGagnon-Grenier I added `Date.now()` because it is now the preferred way, and lots of people don't like `+new Date`. I like that daveb's answer now includes `+new Date`, and explains it, but it didn't used to either.

Comment: So to retrieve a numeric value that is already inside your computer you create an object, call an operator that requires an int and triggers a  conversion that calls a function (valueOf) that calls the class conversion method that calls the function (getTime) that finally retrieves the value that was already there. Then the object is abandoned to its destiny, and after 1000 iterations of the loop you have 1000 deleted Date objects requiring garbage collection hanging there that suddenly get all dumped together, and while your computer lags you wonder what is happening. :)

Comment: +0 for "*and over 357 people voted that it's better*" because we don't give votes for funny on SO. But +1 for good answer. And because it's funny. ;^) (I do get tired of "looks like a typo" complaints when it's a language feature. `~~` is a great truncate, but folks lodge the same complaint. But if it weren't there, someone'd invent it, you know? Learn the language, 357 people! It's fun.)

Comment: In case you wonder about the logic of `plus` sign is: `+` is used as `toInt()` where it will neglect all the characters and return only numbers

Answer (score 317):

JavaScript works with the number of milliseconds since the epoch whereas most other languages work with the seconds. You could work with milliseconds but as soon as you pass a value to say PHP, the PHP native functions will probably fail. So to be sure I always use the seconds, not milliseconds.

This will give you a Unix timestamp (in seconds):

```
var unix = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
```

This will give you the milliseconds since the epoch (not Unix timestamp):

```
var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it doesn't smuggle in the apparent bias for Math.floor(). Math.floor() can have a rounding inaccuracy of up to one second, whereas Math.round()'s inaccuracy approaches only half a second.

I think the argument for Math.floor() is that it avoids a "now" timestamp that is technically slightly into the future. Why is that so egregious compared to a "now" timestamp that can be more in the past? Using Math.floor(), which is potentially more inaccurate, simply because it can't produce a "future" timestamp wreaks of over-thinking it.

Answer (score 164):

***I provide multiple solutions with descriptions in this answer. Feel free to ask questions if anything is unclear***

---

**Quick and dirty solution:**

```
Date.now() /1000 |0
```

> ***Warning**: it **might** break in 2038 and return negative numbers if you do the `|0` magic. Use `Math.floor()` instead by that time*

**`Math.floor()` solution:**

```
Math.floor(Date.now() /1000);
```

---

**Some nerdy alternative by [Derek 朕會功夫](//stackoverflow.com/users/283863) taken from the comments below this answer:**

```
new Date/1e3|0
```

---

**Polyfill to get `Date.now()` working:**

To get it working in IE you could do this (Polyfill from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)):

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function now() {
        return new Date().getTime();
    };
}
```

---

**If you do not care about the year / day of week / daylight saving time you need to remember this for dates after 2038:**

Bitwise operations will cause usage of 32 Bit Integers instead of 64 Bit Floating Point.

You will need to properly use it as:

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

---

If you just want to know the relative time from the point of when the code was run through first you could use something like this:

```
const relativeTime = (() => {
    const start = Date.now();
    return () => Date.now() - start;
})();
```

---

**In case you are using jQuery you could use `$.now()` as described in [jQuery's Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.now/) which makes the polyfill obsolete since `$.now()` internally does the same thing: `(new Date).getTime()`**

If you are just happy about jQuery's version, consider upvoting [**this**](//stackoverflow.com/a/15434736/1519836) answer since I did not find it myself.

---

**Now a tiny explaination of what `|0` does:**

By providing `|`, you tell the interpreter to do a binary OR operation.
Bit operations require absolute numbers which turns the decimal result from `Date.now() / 1000` into an integer.

During that conversion, decimals are removed, resulting in a similar result to what using `Math.floor()` would output.

> **Be warned though:** it will convert a 64 bit double to a 32 bit integer.
> This will result in information loss when dealing with huge numbers.
> Timestamps will break after 2038 due to 32 bit integer overflow unless Javascript moves to 64 Bit Integers in Strict Mode.

---

**For further information about `Date.now` follow this link: [`Date.now()` @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)**

Answer (score 162):

```
var time = Date.now || function() {
  return +new Date;
};

time();
```

Answer (score 103):

```
var timestamp = Number(new Date()); // current time as number
```

Answer (score 96):

In addition to the other options, if you want a dateformat ISO, you can get it directly

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

Answer (score 64):

*jQuery* provides [its own method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/) to get the timestamp:

```
var timestamp = $.now();
```

<sup>(besides it just implements `(new Date).getTime()` expression)</sup>

**REF:** http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/

Answer (score 55):

**Date**, a **native object** in JavaScript is the way we get all data about time.

Just be careful in JavaScript the timestamp depends on the client computer set, so it's not 100% accurate timestamp. To get the best result, you need to get the timestamp from the **server-side**.

Anyway, my preferred way is using vanilla. This is a common way of doing it in JavaScript:

```
Date.now(); //return 1495255666921
```

In MDN it's mentioned as below:

> The Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since
>   1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.
>   Because now() is a static method of Date, you always use it as Date.now().

If you using a version below ES5, `Date.now();` not works and you need to use:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks, I went through tons of answers all over the net and was getting to this conclusions but nobody to confirm it.

Answer (score 52):

## Performance

Today - 2020.04.23 I perform tests for chosen solutions. I tested on MacOs High Sierra 10.13.6 on Chrome 81.0, Safari 13.1, Firefox 75.0

#### Conclusions

- Solution `Date.now()` (E) is fastest on Chrome and Safari and second fast on Firefox and this is probably best choice for fast cross-browser solution
- Solution `performance.now()` (G), what is surprising, is more than 100x faster than other solutions on Firefox but slowest on Chrome
- Solutions C,D,F are quite slow on all browsers

[image]

#### Details

Results for chrome

[image]

You can perform test on your machine [HERE](https://jsbench.me/f5k9ckm6lh/1)

Code used in tests is presented in below snippet

```js
function A() {
  return new Date().getTime();
}

function B() {
  return new Date().valueOf();
}

function C() {
  return +new Date();
}

function D() {
  return new Date()*1;
}

function E() {
  return Date.now();
}

function F() {
  return Number(new Date());
}

function G() {
  // this solution returns time counted from loading the page.
  // (and on Chrome it gives better precission)
  return performance.now(); 
}



// TEST

log = (n,f) => console.log(`${n} : ${f()}`);

log('A',A);
log('B',B);
log('C',C);
log('D',D);
log('E',E);
log('F',F);
log('G',G);
```

```html
This snippet only presents code used in external benchmark
```

Answer (score 51):

```js
console.log(new Date().valueOf()); // returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch
```

Answer (score 50):

Just to add up, here's a function to return a timestamp string in Javascript. 
Example: 15:06:38 PM

```
function displayTime() {
    var str = "";

    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds
    }
    str += hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";
    if(hours > 11){
        str += "PM"
    } else {
        str += "AM"
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 36):

One I haven't seen yet

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // current time in seconds
```

Another one I haven't seen yet is

```
var _ = require('lodash'); // from here https://lodash.com/docs#now
_.now();
```

Answer (score 32):

The [`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method can be used with a little tweak:

> The value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds
>   since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Divide the result by 1000 to get the Unix timestamp, [`floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) if necessary:

```
(new Date).getTime() / 1000
```

---

<sup>The `Date.valueOf()` method is functionally equivalent to `Date.getTime()`, which makes it possible to use arithmetic operators on date object to achieve identical results. In my opinion, this approach affects readability.</sup>

Answer (score 28):

The code `Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)` can be shortened to `new Date / 1E3 | 0`.

Consider to skip direct [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) invocation and use `| 0` as a replacement for [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) function.
It's also good to remember `1E3` is a shorter equivalent for `1000` (uppercase E is preferred than lowercase to indicate `1E3` as a constant).

As a result you get the following:

```js
var ts = new Date / 1E3 | 0;

console.log(ts);
```

Answer (score 25):

I highly recommend using `moment.js`. To get the number of milliseconds since UNIX epoch, do

```
moment().valueOf()
```

To get the number of seconds since UNIX epoch, do

```
moment().unix()
```

You can also convert times like so:

```
moment('2015-07-12 14:59:23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').valueOf()
```

I do that all the time. No pun intended.

To use `moment.js` in the browser:

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script>
    moment().valueOf();
</script>
```

For more details, including other ways of installing and using MomentJS, see their [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 24):

For a timestamp with microsecond resolution, there's [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now):

```
function time() { 
  return performance.now() + performance.timing.navigationStart;
}
```

This could for example yield `1436140826653.139`, while `Date.now` only gives `1436140826653`.

Comment: Documented to have millisecond resolution, not microsecond. Also `performance.timing.navigationStart` is deprecated.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a simple function to generate timestamp in the format: mm/dd/yy hh:mi:ss

```
function getTimeStamp() {
    var now = new Date();
    return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
            (now.getDate()) + '/' +
             now.getFullYear() + " " +
             now.getHours() + ':' +
             ((now.getMinutes() < 10)
                 ? ("0" + now.getMinutes())
                 : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' +
             ((now.getSeconds() < 10)
                 ? ("0" + now.getSeconds())
                 : (now.getSeconds())));
}
```

Comment: @b123400 - Here's the Lisp version: `(new (chain (-date) (to-i-s-o-string)))`.

Answer (score 22):

```js
// The Current Unix Timestamp
// 1443534720 seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC)

// seconds
console.log(Math.floor(new Date().valueOf() / 1000)); // 1443534720
console.log(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)); // 1443534720
console.log(Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)); // 1443534720

// milliseconds
console.log(Math.floor(new Date().valueOf())); // 1443534720087
console.log(Math.floor(Date.now())); // 1443534720087
console.log(Math.floor(new Date().getTime())); // 1443534720087

// jQuery
// seconds
console.log(Math.floor($.now() / 1000)); // 1443534720
// milliseconds
console.log($.now()); // 1443534720087
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 22):

You can only use

```js
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(timestamp);
```

to get the current timestamp. No need to do anything extra.

Answer (score 22):

If it is for logging purposes, you can use **ISOString**

`new Date().toISOString()`

> "2019-05-18T20:02:36.694Z"

Answer (score 17):

Any browsers not supported Date.now, you can use this for get current date time:

```
currentTime = Date.now() || +new Date()
```

Comment: (Rephrasing my comment) Your code has a problem: it executes Date.now method instead of checking its support first. On older browsres it will cause _Date.now is not a function_ error.

Comment: Perhaps a better alternative would be to use a ternary operator to assert that `Date.now` actually exists (and is a function), before attempting to invoke it: `currentTime = typeof Date.now === "function" ? Date.now() : +new Date()`.

Answer (score 17):

This seems to work.

```
console.log(clock.now);
// returns 1444356078076

console.log(clock.format(clock.now));
//returns 10/8/2015 21:02:16

console.log(clock.format(clock.now + clock.add(10, 'minutes'))); 
//returns 10/8/2015 21:08:18

var clock = {
    now:Date.now(),
    add:function (qty, units) {
            switch(units.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'weeks'   :  val = qty * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;  break;
                case 'days'    :  val = qty * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;  break;
                case 'hours'   :  val = qty * 1000 * 60 * 60;  break;
                case 'minutes' :  val = qty * 1000 * 60;  break;
                case 'seconds' :  val = qty * 1000;  break;
                default       :  val = undefined;  break;
                }
            return val;
            },
    format:function (timestamp){
            var date = new Date(timestamp);
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = date.getDate();
            var hours = date.getHours();
            var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
            var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
            // Will display time in xx/xx/xxxx 00:00:00 format
            return formattedTime = month + '/' + 
                                day + '/' + 
                                year + ' ' + 
                                hours + ':' + 
                                minutes.substr(-2) + 
                                ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
            }
};
```

Answer (score 15):

This one has a solution : which converts unixtime stamp to tim in js try this

```
var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp*1000);
var hour = a.getUTCHours();
var min = a.getUTCMinutes();
var sec = a.getUTCSeconds();
```

Answer (score 15):

I learned a really cool way of converting a given Date object to a Unix timestamp from the source code of [JQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js) the other day.

Here's an example:

```
var date = new Date();
var timestamp = +date;
```

Comment: I was about to write the new Date() Object .You can console log(new Date()) and then skim through the related methods under the new Date() object/ function

Answer (score 15):

If want a basic way to generate a timestamp in Node.js this works well.

```
var time = process.hrtime();
var timestamp = Math.round( time[ 0 ] * 1e3 + time[ 1 ] / 1e6 );
```

Our team is using this to bust cache in a localhost environment. The output is `/dist/css/global.css?v=245521377` where `245521377` is the timestamp generated by `hrtime()`.

Hopefully this helps, the methods above can work as well but I found this to be the simplest approach for our needs in Node.js.

Answer (score 13):

For [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#now) and [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#now) users, use `_.now`.

```
var timestamp = _.now(); // in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 12):

As of writing this, the top answer is 9 years old, and a lot has changed since then - not least, we have near universal support for a non-hacky solution:

```
Date.now()
```

If you want to be absolutely certain that this won't break in some ancient (pre ie9) browser, you can put it behind a check, like so:

```
const currentTimestamp = (!Date.now ? +new Date() : Date.now());
```

This will return the milliseconds since epoch time, of course, not seconds.

[MDN Documentation on Date.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Answer (score 11):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) can abstract away a lot of the pain in dealing with Javascript Dates.

See: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/

```
moment().unix();
```

Comment: Note that this gives the number of seconds (not milliseconds) since UNIX epoch. If you want the milliseconds, use `moment().valueOf()`. See my answer.

Answer (score 10):

more simpler way:

```
var timeStamp=event.timestamp || new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: Do know where `event` comes from. You need to give a better explanation of the way you resolve it instead of you writing an answer. Please!

Comment: I was about to write the new Date() Object .You can console log(new Date()) and then skim through the related methods under the new Date() object/ function

Answer (score 9):

sometime I need it in objects for xmlhttp calls, so I do like this.

```
timestamp : parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000, 10)
```

Comment: Even shorter: `new Date().getTime()/1000|0` but its slow and dirty

Comment: I was about to write the new Date() Object .You can console log(new Date()) and then skim through the related methods under the new Date() object/ function

Answer (score 7):

**Get TimeStamp In JavaScript**

> In JavaScript, a timestamp is the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970.
>
> If you don't intend to support < IE8, you can use

```
new Date().getTime(); + new Date(); and Date.now();
```

to directly get the timestamp without having to create a new Date object.

> To return the required timestamp

```
new Date("11/01/2018").getTime()
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
//if you need 10 digits
   alert('timestamp '+ts());
function ts() {
    return parseInt(Date.now()/1000);

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.valueOf());
```

Comment: I was about to write the new Date() Object .You can console log(new Date()) and then skim through the related methods under the new Date() object/ function.  the new Date().getTime()  method will give you the time in the EPOCH format which can be interpreted if necessary

Answer (score 5):

The advised, proper way is `Number(new Date())`, 
in terms of code- readability,

Also, UglifyJS and Google-Closure-Compiler will lower the complexity of the parsed code-logic-tree (relevant if you are using one of them to obscure/minify your code).

for Unix timestamp, which has a lower time resolution,  just divide current number with `1000`, keeping the whole.

Answer (score 5):

I had to create a TIMESTAMP although the type on my DB mapping was String, for that I used

```
new Date().toISOString();
```

the output is like "2023-01-09T14:11:31.931Z"

Answer (score 4):

`var my_timestamp = ~~(Date.now()/1000);`

Answer (score 3):

there are many ways to do it.

```
 Date.now() 
 new Date().getTime() 
 new Date().valueOf()
```

> To get the timestamp in seconds, convert it using:

```
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution to generate a timestamp in JavaScript - including a padding method for single numbers - using day, month, year, hour, minute and seconds in its result (working example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AcLzd/9/)):

```
var pad = function(int) { return int < 10 ? 0 + int : int; };
var timestamp = new Date();

    timestamp.day = [
        pad(timestamp.getDate()),
        pad(timestamp.getMonth() + 1), // getMonth() returns 0 to 11.
        timestamp.getFullYear()
    ];

    timestamp.time = [
        pad(timestamp.getHours()),
        pad(timestamp.getMinutes()),
        pad(timestamp.getSeconds())
    ];

timestamp.now = parseInt(timestamp.day.join("") + timestamp.time.join(""));
alert(timestamp.now);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getTimeStamp() {
    var now = new Date();
    return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +
            (now.getDate()) + '/' +
             now.getFullYear() + " " +
             now.getHours() + ':' +
             ((now.getMinutes() < 10)
                 ? ("0" + now.getMinutes())
                 : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' +
             ((now.getSeconds() < 10)
                 ? ("0" + now.getSeconds())
                 : (now.getSeconds())));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> To get time, month, day, year separately this will work

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Equivalent to PHP's time(), which returns
 * current Unix timestamp.
 *
 * @param  {string}  unit    - Unit of time to return.
 *                           - Use 's' for seconds and 'ms' for milliseconds.
 * @return {number}
 */
time(unit = 's') {
    return unit == 's' ? Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) : Date.now()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the upcoming Temporal API (stage 3), you can use the `epoch*` properties on [`Temporal.Instant`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/instant.html).

For example, for the current timestamp in milliseconds you can use [`Temporal.Now`](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/now.html)

```js
const instant = Temporal.Now.instant();
const timestamp = instant.epochMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score -21):

```
time = Math.round(((new Date()).getTime()-Date.UTC(1970,0,1))/1000);
```

Comment: @Skone technically nothing is screwed up. `Date.UTC(1970,0,1)` will *always* evaluate to 0, no matter what time zone the user is in. still, I'd say this is a bad answer because of it.

Comment: @Kip Good point.  We're both getting at the same thing though, the additional arithmetic here is unnecessary.

Comment: If the Epoch changes, the definition of Unix Timestamp changes. That makes the above code backwards compatible, but broken :)