# What does the plus sign do in '+new Date'

Tags: javascript, syntax

I've seen this in a few [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript#221357)

```
function fn() {
    return +new Date;
}
```

And I can see that it is returning a timestamp rather than a date object, but I can't find any documentation on what the plus sign is doing.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of a plus symbol before a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-plus-symbol-before-a-variable)

Answer (score 323, accepted):

That's the `+` unary operator. It's equivalent to:

```
function(){ return Number(new Date); }
```

See http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

Comment: Good stuff - "Values of type Date will be converted to their corresponding numerical value (via valueOf()), which is the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch."

Comment: But like why wouldn't you use the defined `getTime` method on the date object?!

Comment: @tkone Some people like it [because it is shorter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5036460/425313).

Comment: Under almost no circumstances should you actually use this. I just really got burnt on this. +new Date() in addition to any kind of mathematical operations will undergo a major performance penalty.

Comment: @BradKoch in programming brevity is most certainly not the wit of the soul. As the python community has so adequately put it "explicit is always better than implicit." What if a browser changed the automatic type conversion that's implied there through a regression? Now your code just doesn't work! `.getTime()` will always insure it does.

Comment: @Geuis another excellent reason that just because you can doesn't meant you should!

Comment: Sine ECMAScript 5 there is `Date.now()`, which is the preferred way to get the date and time in milliseconds.

Comment: Another trick is to `var x = ~~y` which converts to integer even if `y` is a float value.

Comment: Just to be sure: `+new Date()` is completely equivalent to `Date.now()` -- yes?

Comment: @YuvalA. Yes, it is completely equivalent, apart from being significantly faster than all other methods: https://jsperf.com/get-unix-time-all-versions/1

Comment: Trivia: "+new Date" is used by Gmail. They don't even put parantheses after it.

Comment: @Geuis can you explain what performance penalty ? testing on https://jsben.ch/ttEBh showed close to 0 difference between +newDate() and new date.getTime(). But Date.now() showed 2.5% better performance

Comment: @strix25 Thanks for replying to my 10 year old coment. =) Sadly jsperf.com closed down a long while back. Right, so basically Date.now() didn't exist back then. `+new Date` uses type coercion, where the standard `new Date().getTime()` doesn't. `+new` is shorthand, but it hides the extra computing steps going on in the background. In most cases, `+new` would be fine, but if you use it in frequently called functions it can be a significant performance hit. Better practice in general is to never use shortcuts like this and just write out your code. Better readability for the future.

Comment: @strix25 Following up on your jsbench profile. Not sure if its yours, but the test cases are way overcomplicated. I created this one https://jsben.ch/iczTu that just tests `+new Date()`, `new Date().getTime()`, and `Date.now()`. On current gen Chrome, the 2nd is about 5% more efficient that the first, and the 3rd is 25% faster.

Comment: @Geuis This is just 1 real world case where function would run this and much more with 6000req/s so even 2% improvement matters

Answer (score 46):

JavaScript is loosely typed, so it performs type coercion/conversion in certain circumstances:

http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/03/understanding-loose-typing-in.html
http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/type_convert.html

Other examples:

```
>>> +new Date()
1224589625406
>>> +"3"
3
>>> +true
1
>>> 3 == "3"
true
```

Comment: >>> 3 === "3"
    false

Answer (score 7):

A JavaScript date can be written as a string:

Thu Sep 10 2015 12:02:54 GMT+0530 (IST)

or as a number:

1441866774938

Dates written as numbers, specifies the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.

Coming to your question it seams that by adding '+' after assignment operator '=' , converting Date to equal number value.

same can be achieve using Number() function, like Number(new Date());

```
var date = +new Date(); //same as 'var date =number(new Date());'
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.6) regarding the "unary add" operator. Hope it helps...

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. This is a great example of why. It's defunct.

Answer (score 3):

If you remember, when you want to find the time difference between two dates, you simply do as follows:

```
var d1 = new Date("2000/01/01 00:00:00"); 
var d2 = new Date("2000/01/01 00:00:01");  //one second later

var t = d2 - d1; //will be 1000 (msec) = 1 sec

typeof t; // "number"
```

Now if you check type of d1-0, it is also a number:

```
t = new Date() - 0; //numeric value of Date: number of msec's since 1 Jan 1970.
typeof t; // "number"
```

That `+` will also convert the Date to Number:

```
typeof (+new Date()) //"number"
```

But note that `0 + new Date()` will **not** be treated similarly! It will be concatenated as string:

```
0 + new Date() // "0Tue Oct 16 05:03:24 PDT 2018"
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a *unary add* operator and also used for explicit Number conversion, so when you call `+new Date()`, it tries to get the numeric value of that object using `valueOf()` like we get string from `toString()`

```
new Date().valueOf() == (+new Date)  // true
```

Answer (score -3):

It does exactly the same thing as:

```
function(){ return 0+new Date; }
```

that has the same result as:

```
function(){ return new Date().getTime(); }
```

Comment: Nope on 0+new Date. That first converts the date to a string and then prepends a "0", (eg: "0Tue Oct 21 2008 20:38:05 GMT-0400");

Comment: 1 * new Date will,  but 1 + new Date --> String

Comment: ya, also the same goes for `new Date/1`