# what is the role of the plus sign(+) in the following function which is excerpt from jquery source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, date

```
function now(){
    return +new Date;
}
```

questions :

1. what does the plus sign mean?
2. when can you create a new object with a constructor function but without the following parentheses, such as `new Date` but not `new Date()`

great thanks!

Comment: 1. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-return-new-date

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 . The plus sign is the unary + operator.

That expression is equivalent to *cast* the Date object to number:

```
function now(){
    return Number(new Date);
}
```

2 . If you don't add the parenthesis, the [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/new_Operator) will call the object type (Date) parameterlessly

Comment: ... and converting a `Date` into a `Number` (any way you do it) is, basically, just a less readable way of invoking `getTime()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Answer (score 3):

1. Using the plus sign will convert the date into a number (the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970)
2. You can do this whenever there are no parameters - although you may wish to include them still for readability.