# What is the purpose of a plus symbol before a variable?

Tags: javascript

What does the `+d` in

```
function addMonths(d, n, keepTime) { 
    if (+d) {
```

mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the plus sign do in 'return +new Date'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-return-new-date)

Comment: Same issue but the title of other page doesn't describe the general case as this does

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does `+…` mean in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15129137/1048572)

Answer (score 539, accepted):

The `+` operator returns the numeric representation of the object.  So in your particular case, it would appear to be predicating the if on whether or not `d` is a non-zero number.

Reference [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Operators#Arithmetic_operators).  And, as pointed out in comments, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).

Comment: Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2b_(Unary_Plus%29

Comment: Working link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()

Comment: I just wonder which is more efficient, parse a string into an integer using the function parseInt or using the plus operator?

Comment: How is it different from `.parseInt()` ?

Comment: @DanielW. 1. `parseInt` will return a whole number, so if you do `parseInt("5.51")` the result would be `5` while `+"5.51"` will give you `5.51`. 2. `parseInt` will *parse* the number from a string and stop at the first non-numeric sign while the unary plus will convert the whole input. So `parseInt("5 bananas") //5` while `+"5 bananas" //NaN`

Comment: @acarlstein whichever it is, I doubt the speed difference actually matters in any meaningful way for the execution of a whole algorithm or even an application. Looking for "efficiency" here is likely a microoptimisation and a premature one at that.

Comment: @VLAZ I will have to disagree. Its all depending what are you programming and where your code will run. For example, if you investigate, there is a difference in processing time between `i++;` and `++i;`. One thing is if your run your code abrowser, where you have the power of the CPU and memory,  and when your code runs, per say, a microcontroller such as Espruino. Sometimes you want to use the less CPU cycles possible.

Comment: @acarlstein it's still premature optimisation. Until you actually find it's a bottleneck, it's not worth spending much time making the numeric conversion faster. And if you are *really* strapped for CPU cycles, then I'd hazard a guess that you shouldn't be running *JavaScript* - an interpreted language. If you still *are* then you have to realise that the interpreter would likely optimise away a lot of cases for you so trying to figure out what is faster is useless when the interpreter turns it all in the same code anyway. `i++` could turn into a straight increment if the value is not used.

Comment: @acarlstein from the MDN link in the answer: "Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, **unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number**, because it does not perform any other operations on the number." (just for an "official" answer)

Comment: Newer link as of 2023 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Unary_plus_()

Answer (score 110):

Operator `+` is a unary operator which converts the value to a number. Below is a table with corresponding results of using this operator for different values.

```
+----------------------------+-----------+
| Value                      | + (Value) |
+----------------------------+-----------+
| 1                          | 1         |
| '-1'                       | -1        |
| '3.14'                     | 3.14      |
| '3'                        | 3         |
| '0xAA'                     | 170       |
| true                       | 1         |
| false                      | 0         |
| null                       | 0         |
| 'Infinity'                 | Infinity  |
| 'infinity'                 | NaN       |
| '10a'                      | NaN       |
| undefined                  | NaN       |
| ['Apple']                  | NaN       |
| function(val){ return val }| NaN       |
+----------------------------+-----------+
```

Operator `+` returns a value for objects which have implemented method `valueOf`.

```javascript
let something = {
    valueOf: function () {
        return 25;
    }
};

console.log(+something);
```

Comment: Important thing:  `1.` and other strings that end with `.` will become fixed by removing the trailing ­`.`.  I stumbled upon this when fixing a bug in some real-time input handler that should allow entering decimal numbers but did not work as expected because of `+` operator trimming away the trailing `.`.

Comment: Remember to use `+` operator with caution in `if` statements as `NaN` neither equals 'true` or `false`:
`if (+function(){ }) console.log('success')` - this will not execute

Comment: @Kutalia `NaN` is falsy, so it would execute anything in an `else` statement

Answer (score 36):

It is a unary "+" operator which yields a numeric expression. It would be the same as `d*1`, I believe.

Comment: Please do not add an answer if you are not totally sure what's happening. I got confused by the I believed, please change it if you are sure about it.

Comment: @Nemesius, good point. The "I believe" part in this answer still holds even though 10 years have passed since I answered it. I am not completely sure, if I can imagine all the possible cases where the two JavaScript "hacks" work the same way. What if `'string'*1` returns something different than `+'string'`? So, it is approximately the same - I believe :)

Comment: `+1n` throws `TypeError` ("Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number"), whereas `1n*1` throws `TypeError` ("Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions"). A minor difference, but the only one I've found thus far (other than the column placement for the error being different).

Answer (score 21):

As explained in other answers it converts the variable to a number. Specially useful when `d` can be either a number or a string that evaluates to a number.

Example (using the `addMonths` function in the question):

```
addMonths(34,1,true);
addMonths("34",1,true);
```

then the `+d` will evaluate to a number in all cases. Thus avoiding the need to check for the type and take different code paths depending on whether `d` is a number, a function or a string that can be converted to a number.

Comment: `+d` will not evaluate to a number with the first invocation example of addMonths

Comment: true, I don't know what I did when I wrote this. `+function(){...}` will produce a `NaN` not evaluate the function

Comment: Could you edit your answer to remove the crazy?   It's pretty confusing.