# Difference between += and =+ in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know why after running the third line of code the result of `a` is 5?

```
a = 10;
b = 5;
a =+ b;
```

Comment: the correct syntax is a+=b; a=+b; is not correct. it is  simply assigning b value to a.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of a plus symbol before a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-plus-symbol-before-a-variable)

Answer (score 51):

Awkward formatting:

```
a =+ b;
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = +b;
```

And `+b` is just a fancy way of casting `b` to number, like here:

```
var str = "123";
var num = +str;
```

You probably wanted:

```
a += b;
```

being equivalent to:

```
a = a + b;
```

Comment: ...while a += b is a shortcut for a = a + b, which is probably what you want

Comment: @fritzfromlondon: Thanks for pointing that out, I allowed myself to add your comment to an answer to better stand out

Comment: The `+` in `a = +b;` is called the *unary `+` operator*: http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6

Answer (score 2):

The + sign before the function, actually called [Unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) and is part of a group called a [Unary Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#unary_operators) and (the Unary Plus) is used to convert string and other representations to numbers (integers or floats).

> A unary operation is an operation with only one operand, i.e. a single input. This is in contrast to binary operations, which use two operands.

**Basic Uses:**

```js
const x = "1";
const y = "-1";
const n = "7.77";

console.log(+x);
// expected output: 1

console.log(+n);
// expected output: 7.77

console.log(+y);
// expected output: -1

console.log(+'');
// expected output: 0

console.log(+true);
// expected output: 1

console.log(+false);
// expected output: 0

console.log(+'hello');
// expected output: NaN
```

When the + sign is positioned before a variable, function or any returned string representations the output will be converted to integer or float; the unary operator (+) converts as well the non-string values true, false, and null.