# What does = +_ mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators

I was wondering what the **= +_** operator means in JavaScript.  It looks like it does assignments.

Example:

```
hexbin.radius = function(_) {
   if (!arguments.length)
       return r;
   r = +_;
   dx = r * 2 * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3);
   dy = r * 1.5;
   return hexbin;
};
```

Comment: Reminded me of the good old *approach* operator [`-->`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/1081234)

Comment: What now - `=+` or `+_`? Please be clear about what you try to ask.

Comment: There is no "`=+`" in the question. There's "`= +`", which is very different. `+ =` would not have worked either, that's a syntax error - you cannot ignore spaces here.

Comment: The + here is a unary operator, with _ as its operand.

Comment: It's just the negative or positive value as in maths (+10 - positive number), (-10 - negative number). No fancy!

Comment: Looks like a Perl programmer couldn't let go of the default variable ;-)

Comment: Just like `$` is a valid Java and Javascript identifier, while you just came from PHP programming. Confusing. Ninja it is!

Comment: A good syntax-highlighting would have helped you to answer the question.

Comment: Wonder what the close vote is about?

Comment: Ok, here is good read: [**Javascript Type-Conversion**](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/) Second is [**Type Casting In Javascript**](http://mahdipedram.com/type-casting-in-javascript/)

Comment: Oh, this was one freaky syntax. Never seen that before and it's got a coolness value of at least 98%. I'm going to use it in the next script just to make people scratch their eyes. :D

Comment: I wonder why someone would use just an underscore(`_`) as a variable. Is it to make people scratch their heads while reading his code or he's being simplistic, to reduce the number of chars of the source code? o.O

Comment: i hate this kind of variable naming, he/she should be idiot to give such name.

Comment: You can make a smiley face `x=  +_+  0;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the plus sign do in 'return +new Date'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-return-new-date)

Answer (score 405, accepted):

```
r = +_;
```

- `+` tries to cast whatever `_` is to a number.
- `_` is only a variable name (not an operator), it could be `a`, `foo` etc.

**Example:**

```
+"1"
```

cast "1" to pure number 1.

```
var _ = "1";
var r = +_;
```

`r` is now `1`, not `"1"`.

Moreover, according to the [MDN page on Arithmetic Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29):

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its
>   operand but **attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't
>   already**. *[...]* It can convert string representations of integers and
>   floats, as well as the non-string values `true`, `false`, and `null`.
>   Integers in both decimal and hexadecimal (`"0x"`-prefixed) formats are
>   supported. Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it
>   cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to `NaN`.

It is also noted that

> unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number

Comment: Does + really mean cast to a number, or does `+_` really mean `0+_`, in which case `_` must be cast before adding to 0?

Comment: @c.cam108 See [the MDN page on the unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

Comment: @c.cam108 - No, they do not behave similarly. Unary plus casts the value to a number, but binary plus does not: `+'12' === 12` (result is a number), but `0 + '12' === '012'` (result is a string). Note, however, that `0 - '12' === -12`.

Comment: @juzerali Sure, but that's not good practice.  Try using addition  ;)

Comment: Looks perlish with perl's default variable $_

Comment: @Alvin Wong I think `X | 0` will be faster then `+`,  **not ?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `+` is faster because `it does not perform any other operations on the number` *(MDN)* Also, bitwise OR `|` only results in an signed integer.

Comment: @Izkata: I know it will concatenate the strings.

Comment: @AlvinWong I don't think so. `|` is much faster. on most browser. may be slow on IE.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Unary `+` converts to **`Number`** but `|` only result in **32-bit signed integer**.

Comment: @AlvinWong **Yes** true! :)

Comment: String concatenation and conversion is a special feature of the binary plus +. Other arithmetic operators work only with numbers and always convert their operands to numbers.

Answer (score 95):

It is not an assignment operator.

- `_` is just a parameter passed to the function.

  ```
  hexbin.radius = function(_) {
                  //       ^ It is passed here
      // ...
  };
  ```
- On the next line `r = +_;` `+` infront casts that variable (`_`) to a number or integer value and assigns it to variable `r`

**DO NOT CONFUSE IT WITH `+=` operator**

Answer (score 54):

`=+` are actually **two** operators `=` is assignment and `+` and  `_` is variable name.

like:

```
i = + 5;
or 
j = + i;
or 
i = + _;
```

My following codes will help you to show use of `=+` to convert a *string*  into *int*.
example:

```
y = +'5'
x = y +5
alert(x);
```

outputs **10**

**use:** So here `y` is int `5` because of `=+`
**otherwise:**

```
y = '5'
x = y +5
alert(x);
```

outputs **55**

Where as `_` is a variable.

```
_ = + '5'
x = _ + 5
alert(x)
```

outputs **10**

**Additionally,**
It would be interesting to know you could also achieve same thing with `~` (if string is *int* string *(float will be round of to int)*)

```
y = ~~'5'  // notice used two time ~
x = y  + 5
alert(x);
```

also outputs **10**

`~` is bitwise NOT : Inverts the bits of its operand. I did twice for no change in magnitude.

Comment: I use often `x|0` to convert double to int; however this as well as using '~' has the penalty of restricting to numbers < 2^32. +"2e15" does not.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Yes good I believe `x|0` is even faster then `+`. Correct **?** nice technique :). (2) I use `~` just to show OP that `+` is not only a sign can be use (*i myself use `+`*).

Comment: Hard to say -- there's jsperf though is one want's to measure it. OTOH these two operators have a complete different meaning. If only requiring a number (and not integer) '+' is anyway one character shorter.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen actually bitwise operators are faster then any other operator. that is the reason!

Comment: Actually I just tested it jsperf -- 18M ops for '|0', 19M ops for '+'; the performance will probably vary from browser to browser. http://jsperf.com/strtoint

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Oh my, just did the jsperf test in Firefox, huge difference.. `|` alot faster.

Answer (score 16):

It's not `=+`. In JavaScript, `+` means change it into number.

`+'32'` returns 32.

`+'a'` returns NaN.

So you may use `isNaN()` to check if it can be changed into number.

Answer (score 16):

It's a sneaky one.

The important thing to understand is that the underscore character here **is actually a variable name**, not an operator.

The plus sign in front of that is getting the positive numerical value of underscore -- ie effectively casting the underscore variable to be an int. You could achieve the same effect with `parseInt()`, but the plus sign casting is likely used here because it's more concise.

And that just leaves the equals sign as just a standard variable assignment.

It's probably not *deliberately* written to confuse, as an experienced Javascript programmer will generally recognise underscore as a variable. But if you don't know that it is definitely very confusing. I certainly wouldn't write it like that; I'm not a fan of short meaningless variable names at the best of times -- If you want short variable names in JS code to save space, use a minifier; don't write it with short variables to start with.

Comment: +1, as you're the only one here to explicitly point out that `_` is a variable.

Comment: @TRiG what about Starx' answer, which does so without being tl;dr?

Answer (score 12):

= +_ will cast _ into a number.

So

```
var _ = "1",
   r = +_;
console.log(typeof r)
```

would output number.

Answer (score 9):

I suppose you mean `r = +_;`? In that case, it's conversion of the parameter to a `Number`. Say `_` is '12.3', then `+'12.3'` returns `12.3`. So in the quoted statement `+_` is assigned to `r`.

Answer (score 6):

`_` is just a a variable name, passed as a parameter of function `hexbin.radius` , and `+` cast it into number

Let me make a exmple same like your function .

```
var hexbin = {},r  ;

hexbin.radius = function(_) {
   if (!arguments.length)
      return r;
   console.log( _ , typeof _ )    
   r = +_;
   console.log( r , typeof r , isNaN(r) );   
}
```

and run this example function .. which outputs

**hexbin.radius( "1");**

```
1 string
1 number false
```

**hexbin.radius( 1 );**

```
1 number
1 number false
```

**hexbin.radius( [] );**

```
[] object
0 number false
```

**hexbin.radius( 'a' );**

```
a string
NaN number true
```

**hexbin.radius( {} );**

```
Object {} object
NaN number true
```

**hexbin.radius( true );**

```
true boolean
1 number false
```

Answer (score 5):

It Will assign new value to left side variable a number.

```
var a=10;
var b="asg";
var c=+a;//return 10
var d=-a;//return -10
var f="10";

var e=+b;
var g=-f;

console.log(e);//NAN
console.log(g);//-10
```

Comment: You forgot a `+` before the `b`.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, `+_` ***is equivalent*** to using the [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) constructor.

In fact, it even works on dates:

```
var d = new Date('03/27/2014');
console.log(Number(d)) // returns 1395903600000
console.log(+d) // returns 1395903600000
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/GCLjd/

---

More information can also be found [on MDN - Unary plus (+) section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)):

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats, as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported. Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

Answer (score 3):

`+_` is almost **equivalent** of `parseFloat(_)` . Observe that `parseInt` will stop at non numeric character such as dot, whereas `parshFloat` will not.

EXP:

```
    parseFloat(2.4) = 2.4 
vs 
    parseInt(2.4) = 2 
vs 
    +"2.4" = 2.4
```

Exp:

```
var _ = "3";
    _ = +_;

console.log(_); // will show an integer 3
```

Very few differences:

- Empty string `""` evaluates to a `0`, while parseInt() evaluates to `NaN`
- For more info look here: **[parseInt vs unary plus - when to use which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106681/parseint-vs-unary-plus-when-to-use-which)**

Comment: I think in first line you wants to say `parseInr(_)` instead of `parseFloat(_)` **?**

Comment: No I meant `float`, because parseInt will stop at non numeric character, parshFloat will not. EXP: `parseFloat(2.4) = 2.4` vs `parseInt(2.4) = 2`.

Answer (score 2):

In this expression:

```
r = +_;
```

- '+' acts here as an unary operator that tries to ***convert*** the value of the right operand. It doesn't convert the operand but the evaluated value. So `_` will stay "1" if it was so originally but the `r` will become pure number.

Consider these cases whether one wants to apply the + for numeric conversion

```
+"-0" // 0, not -0
+"1" //1
+"-1" // -1
+"" // 0, in JS "" is converted to 0
+null // 0, in JS null is converted to 0
+undefined // NaN
+"yack!" // NaN
+"NaN" //NaN
+"3.14" // 3.14

var _ = "1"; +_;_ // "1"
var _ = "1"; +_;!!_ //true
var _ = "0"; +_;!!_ //true
var _ = null; +_;!!_ //false
```

Though, it's the fastest numeric converter I'd hardly recommend one to overuse it if make use of at all. `parseInt/parseFloat` are good more readable alternatives.