# What does plus operator mean in Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

While I was seeing Underscore.js (version 1.4.3) code, I saw following lines (79 line)

```
   if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
        for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
    }
```

I didn't understand why `+` operator used within **if** statement. (+obj.length) 
And, isn't it this statement always **true**?
I don't think it's a typo. There must be some aim to use that. If anyone knows benefits of this usage, I want to use it in future.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does = +\_ mean in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj.length` might be any type - such as `undefined`. `+obj.length` is always a number.

So the code basically checks if the `length` property exists and is a number. The reason for this check is that `_.each()` accepts both arrays and non-array objects. In case of an array the `length` property is necessary to iterate over its elements while a `for..in` loop is the way to go in case of a non-array object.

Answer (score 1):

The plus operator converts a value to Number.

Basically, `a === +a` makes sure a is a number and not a string.

Answer (score 1):

It converts a value to a number. I found this article helpful:

http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

The unary `+` operator results in the numeric equivalent of its operand, and `NaN` if the operand cannot be converted to a number.

It's one of a number of little "tricks" that exist in Javascript:

- `!!foo` - converts `foo` to a boolean
- `~~foo` - converts `foo` to a 32-bit signed integer