# Difference between using + and | operators in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, operators

I was looking into the AngularJS Framework. I found that they were using `|` operator to add things up. What is the difference when you use `+` operator and `|` operator?

Is it related to performance? If so how?

Here is the Code that was Requested:-

```
var manualLowercase = function(s) {
    return isString(s)
        ? s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(ch) {
            return String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) | 32);
    }): s;
};
```

Comment: add things? add what things? | is bitwise or, + is arithmatic addition or string concatenation

Comment: Basic arithmetic. Is there any performance constraint?

Comment: Could you provide the code where you're seeing this?

Comment: The performance impact will be negligible in almost any code you care to write. `+` and `|` are both blindingly fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are different operators.

Where `x` and `y` are numbers<sup>2</sup>, `x | y` is a [bit-wise or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) and `x + y` is addition. For *some* values of `x` and `y` they will have the same results - for everything else, the result will be different<sup>3</sup>.

Anyway, use the form that means what is desired<sup>1</sup>. Don't worry about performance unless there is a performance case - [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) is a handy tool for this. Then realize that micro-benchmarks and inherently biased and it [*usually doesn't matter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

---

<sup>1</sup> For this *particular* problem, note the regular expression matches each A-Z character and replaces it with the result of the function.

Thus we know that `charCodeAt(0)` is the character code for A..Z. Looking at a [character table](http://www.asciitable.com/) we can see these values are in the range [0x41, 0x5a] and note that [0x61, 0x7a] are the corresponding lower-case letters. Thus we can go { A, B .. Z } -> { a, b .. z } by adding 0x20 (or 32) to the upper-case letter's character code.

It can also be observed that adding 32 (or 1 << 5) to a number *without* the 5th bit set (such as number in the range [0x41, 0x5a]) can be achieved with a bit-wise or with 1 << 5 (i.e x 
| 32). This is why `|` and `+` are interchangeable *here*. Adding 32 (i.e. x + 0x20) is arguably more clear even though both operators will behave equivalently under the rules above.

In any case, if curious about performance implications of either approach, benchmark the code *in it's entirety* (and *in context*) on the relevant/target environments.

---

<sup>2</sup> The operator `x | y` is *always* a bit-wise or (via `[ToInt]` conversions), but `x + y` *could* be a string concatenation.

<sup>3</sup> The results will be the same *only when* `x` and `y` are both numbers (or rather, neither is a string), are convertible via `[ToInt]`, have *no* set bits in common, and are in the range of about [0, 2^32) or so.

Answer (score 4):

`+` is addition operator, `|` is bitwise operator. But because you says "Is it related to performance?" 
so I think your means which is better between below two:

```
x = 0 | '5';
```

or

```
x = + '5';
```

according to [MDN page on Arithmetic Operators:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29)

> unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number

additionally, read comments to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript/15129174#15129174) some browsers performs better with `|` instead.

Also read [wiki: *Bitwise operation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

> On simple low-cost processors, typically, **bitwise operations are substantially faster** than division, several times faster than multiplication, and sometimes significantly faster than addition

Here is an [interesting link 'jsperf'](http://jsperf.com/strtoint) for you.

Comment: `x = | '5';` is not JavaScript.

Comment: @pst Yes you are correct because of `+` I made mistake with `|` Now corrected.

Comment: Interesting, I did not consider that use of `|` or unary `+`. There is also the `x << 0` approach ..

Comment: @pst did you read answer here [What does = +_ mean in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript/15129174#15129174) I also answered there and `~~` can also use :)

Answer (score 1):

I am a just starting to learn javascript. Till now I heard about "+" operator which is used to add two string values or two values. If you add a number and string then it will provide string result only. If you provide both number then I gives the result of two number addition.

Answer (score -1):

When operating in binary variables we can use **or(|)** instead of **plus(+)** operator. It will give the same result. You may want to know about the binary arithmetic. Just google and you will stumble upon may good searches.

Comment: `|` is a bitwise **or**, not a bitwise **and**. Also, it's incorrect that they will give the same result. Compare `true | true` with `true + true`.

Comment: oops really sorry about that. Corrected that one. But isn't `true | true` and `true + true` will give same result, when they are binary vars.

Comment: No, `true | true === 1` and `true + true === 2`. So they have different results. Both of those values would be `true` if you evaluated them as booleans, but that's not the same as getting equivalent results.