# how do you get the integer value of a field?

Tags: javascript

I had to use this to get the integer value of a field:

```
var local = {};
local.result = $('#myID').val();
local.result = parseInt(0 + local.result);
return local.result;
```

Q: Is there a best practice instead, like some sort of jQuery method that returns a value or the number 0 if it's not a value?

I gotta have more jQuery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `+val` to attempt to coerce any string `str` to a number.

If you have possible non-numeric values, and want to default to 0, as in your original post:

```
var num = +str || 0;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F8wWN/2/

Related JS ninja tricks: [What does = +_ mean in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript)

I'm not sure if you are implying any float conversion. It seems it's already an integer because otherwise you wouldn't be able to `parseInt` on it, right?

Comment: So return +$('#myID').val()?

Comment: When you write it that way, it's probably applying the `+` to `$` instead of the value.

Comment: OK, I think @Kolink has a good answer because he has taken jQuery out of it all together.  Although maybe I could write a jQuery plugin to return a value...

Comment: It has nothing to do with jQuery. You can use that to convert any string to a number.

Comment: Your fiddle returns NaN if I give it something that's not a number.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will fail dismally in some browsers, as they will see the number starting with `0` as being base-8. Try this instead:

```
return parseInt(document.getElementById('myID').value,10) || 0;
```

Comment: Note that in [ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2): "The specification of the function parseInt no longer allows implementations to treat Strings beginning with a 0 character as octal values." But they do.

Answer (score 0):

"Best practice" is relative: what is best for someone else may not be best for you.

If you want to check if the value is a positive integer, then a regular expression may fit the bill:

```
var intRe = /^\d+$/;
var el = document.getElementById('id');
el.value = intRe.test(el.value)? el.value || 0;
```

if you want to test for negative integers, modify the regular expression to allow an optional leading minus sign (-):

```
var intRe = /^\-?d+$/;
```

You may want to trim leading and trailing white space for convenience. Note that 2.343e3 is a valid positive integer.