# JavaScript adding a string to a number

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, operators

I was reading the [re-introduction to JavaScript on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript?redirect=no) and in the section *Numbers* it said that you can convert a string to a number simply by adding a plus operator in front of it.

For example:

+"42" which would yield the number output of 42.

But further along in the section about *Operators* it says that by adding a string "something" to any number you can convert that number to a string. They also provide the following example which confused me:

"3" + 4 + 5 would presumably yield a string of 345 in the output, because numbers 4 and 5 would also be converted to strings.

However, wouldn't 3 + 4 + "5" yield a number of 12 instead of a string 75 as was stated in their example?

In this second example in the section about operators wouldn't the + operator which is standing in front of a string "5" convert that string into number 5 and then add everything up to equal 12?

Comment: Read this: [what is =+_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What you are talking about is a unary plus. It is different than the plus that is used with string concatenation or addition.

If you want to use a unary plus to convert and have it added to the previous value, you need to double up on it.

```
> 3 + 4 + "5"
"75"
> 3 + 4 + +"5"
12
```

Edit:

You need to learn about order of operations:

`+` and `-` have the same precedence and are associated to the left:

```
 > 4 - 3 + 5
 (4 - 3) + 5
 1 + 5
 6
```

`+` associating to the left again:

```
> 3 + 4 + "5"
(3 + 4) + "5"
7 + "5"
75
```

unary operators normally have stronger precedence than binary operators:

```
> 3 + 4 + +"5"
(3 + 4) + (+"5")
7 + (+"5")
7 + 5
12
```

Comment: So does that mean that when a string is combined with other numbers it converts all other numbers to strings except when I specifically put another + operator in front of it (essentially two + operators (+ + "5")) and then and only then, JavaScript would interpret what's inside of a string as a number?

Comment: @SineLaboreNihil In `(+ + "5"))` first is for `add` second used to typecase `"5"` string to `5` int ..read the link

Comment: @epascarello I get the order of operations I was just confused by the following sentence on MDN website: "If you add a string to a number (or other value) everything is converted in to a string first." It doesn't say anything about the order in which it is converted. Additionally the following sentence added to the confusion: "Adding an empty string to something is a useful way of converting it." It doesn't say that it would convert everything to a string only after it is detected as a string by JavaScript and that everything before it would remain intact. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: Minus, on the other hand isn't so special. So `"2" - 1` returns `1`, but `"2" + -1` returns `"2-1"`. Debug your heart out! :P

Comment: @poshest - actually, `"unary -"` behaves exactly the same as `"unary +"`. `"2" + +1` would convert the number `+1` to a string (therefore `"1"`), then concatenate the two strings. Your example converts the number `-1` to a string (therefore `"-1"`), then concatenates the two strings. It is quite consistent.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Well, sort of. My example highlights the difference between addition `+` which can coerce the operands from numbers to strings (as Moritz's answer here makes explicit) compared to minus `-`, which cannot. I was not seeking to point out any inconsistency in `unary +` vs `unary -`. As you said, there isn't one.

Comment: @poshest - ahh, I see your point now. Thanks. The comparison that would have made it clear to me what you were saying is `"2" - 1` => `1` but `"2" + 1` => `"21"`. The use of `-1` (unary minus) in your second snippet isn't relevant to the point, IMHO, and threw off my understanding. Your point is simply that `-` doesn't have the "operator ambiguity" that `+` does.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I think my point back then was that I was confused. Much clearer now having re-examined in light of your comment. So thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You could also use parseInt() or parseFloat(), like this:

```
> 1 + 2 + "3"
"33"
> 1 + 2 + parseInt(3)
6
```

I think that's alot cleaner than using +"3", but that is just my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

The answer can be found in Ecma262.pdf section 11.6.1:

> If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then a. Return the
>   String that is the result of concatenating ToString( lprim) followed
>   by ToString(rprim).

So that will resolve all operations according to precedence, so that as soon the string is found any number, the number is converted to string.

```
4 + 3 + "5"
"75"
4 + 3 + "5" + 3
"753"
```

To read the whole standard, go [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Answer (score 3):

When you look at Step 7 and "Note 2" at   [The Addition operator ( + )](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) (§11.6.1) in the ES5 specs,

it says

> If Type(lprim) is String` **or** Type(rprim) is String, then
> Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)

---

> NOTE 2 Step 7 differs from step 3 of the comparison algorithm for the relational operators (11.8.5), by using the logical-or operation instead of the logical-and operation.

Meaning if either `7` (`3+4`) **or** `"5"` (*`||` not `&&`*) is `typeof "string"` `toString()` is applied to both operands.

So the addition is actually applied to

`"7"` and `"5"` -> `"7" + "5" //"75"`

Answer (score 2):

A smple + operator in javascript is used for concatenation and not to add.

A bracket and a + operator before the string format integer variable will do the job every time.

This always works fine.

```
1 + (+"2") = 3
```

Because placing + before string converts the string variable into number.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xuVur/2/

Answer (score 1):

In the example of 3 + 4 + "5" - the Javascript parser will do (3+4)+"5", as the 3+4 is first - so it will add 3 + 4 because they are numbers, then concatenate the string "5".

Comment: This is what's confusing me and I'm pasting it here as it is written on the MDN website: "If you add a string to a number (or other value) everything is converted in to a string first."... So apparently this only works if you add a string first, before the numbers. If you add it after the numbers the numbers will add up (plain math) and then concatenate a string to it afterwards. Meaning that in this case everything won't be converted to a string.

Comment: Not technically correct, as although Javascript isn't typed, it will still preserve types unless you convert, such as int->string, string->int.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a number and a string in Javascript the result is always a string.

Check the experiment here - http://jsfiddle.net/xuVur/1/

```
var a = "3" + 4 + 5;
var b = 3 + 4 + "5";

$("#result1").html(a); // prints 345
$("#result2").html(b); //prints 75
```

Comment: Your are printing `a` always

Answer (score 0):

It is confusing, but binary + seems to be a rare case of a number being coerced to a string.  In most cases it would be the other way round (so it's very easy to think that you don't need to be too fussy about the type)

4+"3" = "43"

4-"3" = 1