# Why isn't my JavaScript variable working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

This works:

```js
$('.sameDiv').css('width', '25%');
```

But this doesn't:

```js
var squaresize = 25;
$('.sameDiv').css('width', 'squaresize%');
```

Also, I've tried it with the percent symbol as part of the variable and that doesn't help.

Comment: What made you think JavaScript would substitute variable names in strings? Given `var foo = 42;` did you think that `var bar = 'foobar';` would be turned into `'42bar'`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript adding a string to a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522648/javascript-adding-a-string-to-a-number)

Comment: For things that are JQuery + Javascript, it's often better to use JQuery in the title instead of Javascript, to get the right folks to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.sameDiv').css('width', 'squaresize%');
```

Should become

```
$('.sameDiv').css('width', squaresize + '%');
```

I did not test it, but if you just put 'squaresize%' it will not try to reference it... rather, just read it directly as a literal string evaluating to "squaresize%" instead of 25%

Comment: Please wrap `.sameDiv` in string delimiters…

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like:

```
var squaresize = 25;

$(".sameDiv").css('width', squaresize+'%');
```

Your variable name is "squaresize". Knowing that when adding a string to an integer will produce a string as well, there is no need to convert your integer to a string. Just add the "%" to your variable value.

Using a single quote, you are setting `css` to value 'square%' as a static value.

Comment: Please do not post solutions, but explain why as well!

Comment: @MichaelVoznesensky but you are right concerning explaining.

Comment: Per Bergi's comment in the other answer: Please wrap .sameDiv in string delimiters…

Comment: @ProllyGeek: FYI, the downvote tooltip text says "This answer is not useful". An answer can contain a correct solution but may not be useful.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the information , but useful is not a digital value , it may vary from person to another such question doesnt really require answering i would flag it as noob question if   there was such option.