# Can someone help explain why it returns a different sum?

Tags: javascript

var x = 10 + Number("1"+"6");
console.log(x);

returns: 26

---

var y = 10 + 1 + 6;
console.log(y);

returns: 17

Comment: Duplicate of [JavaScript adding a string to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522648/javascript-adding-a-string-to-a-number)

Answer (score 4):

You're adding two strings together inside `Number(...)`:

```
"1" + "6" = "16"
```

So the line basically comes down to:

```
var x = 10 + Number( "16" )
> 26
```

Answer (score -1):

In your first example Number("1"+"6"), "1" and "6" evaluate as strings (because of the quotes). When JS adds strings it concatenates them, so "1" + "6" becomes "16" the same way that "Hello " + "world" becomes "Hello world".

In your second example all of the numbers are treated as numbers, so they are added as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and help. Much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

"1"+"6" = "16" : concatenation fo 2 strings
Number("1"+"6") = Number("16") = 16

10 + 16 = 26

```
    let x = 10 + Number("1") + Number("6"); //for x to equal 17
```

here a function i use to sum numbers regardless of arguments are numbers or strings (return null if any of the arguments is not a number)

```
function sumNumbers(){
    let result = 0;
    for(arg of arguments){
        let nArg = Number(arg);
        if(isNaN(nArg)){
            return null;
        };
        result+=nArg; 
    }
    return result;
}
```