# Comparing sum of points to the ideal sum of points

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I am trying to generate an golf scoring system. In  this system I want to compare the amount of points the user have against the ideal sum of points.

The ideal sum of points for each hole is 2. So when a user after 1'st hole has 2 points the return should be 0. If the user on the next hole makes 3 points the return should then be 1. If he only makes 1 point it should be -1.

Some how I can't get this to work!?!?

Here is my demoscript:

```
var myObject = {
    0: 0,
    1: 0,
    2: 0,
    3: 0,
    4: 0,
    5: 0,
    6: 0,
    7: 0,
    8: 0
};

$('.clickme').click(function () {

    var thisNumber = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var thisNumber = thisNumber.split('-');
    var n = thisNumber[0];
    var r = thisNumber[1];

    myObject[n] = r;

    var totalpoints = 0;

    for (var l = 0; l < n + 1; l++) {
        totalpoints += myObject[l];
    }

    //alert("Totalpoints: "+totalpoints);

    // ADDING POINTS FOR EACH HOLE TO GET THE CURRENT IDEAL POINT //
    var x = n;
    var idealpoints = (x * 2) + 2;

    // COMPARING IDEAL POINTS WITH HE PLAYERS ACTUAL POINTS //
    var escore = totalpoints - idealpoints;

    $('#tpoints').html(escore);
    $('#theObject').html(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 4));

});
```

My trouble seems to come from this:

```
for (var l = 0; l < n + 1; l++) {
            totalpoints += myObject[l];
        }
```

I thinks I have tried everything, but can't solve this.

A jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmansa/AtkVp/

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop isn't summing the values because the values have been converted to strings with the `split()` method.

I'm having trouble understanding exactly what the script is supposed to do, but if you change

```
var r = thisNumber[1];
```

to

```
var r = parseInt(thisNumber[1]);
```

`r` will be an integer that will get added to `totalpoints` as opposed to being concatenated to it as a string

Further, you're getting undefined values when values of the object haven't been defined yet. In your for loop, you should do this:

```
if(myObject[l]) {
    totalpoints += myObject[l];
}
```

I have applied my changes to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AtkVp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `n` and `r` variables are strings, not parsed to numbers. This will lead to

- an odd loop condition. When `n` is `"1"`, it will loop `l` until `"1"+1` == `"11"`. That way many zeros and even sum `undefined`s from non-existing properties will get summed up.
- The sum itself is flawed. Instead of adding, it will do string concatenation. `0`+ "1"+"0"+"0" is `"0100"`, not `1`. Also when your concatenating `undefined` the result will not even be a number. You probably have seen those when `alert`ing the `totalpoints`.

When you're going to substract that from the `idealPoints` you get `NaN`, and that won't be displayed.

To fix it, simply cast `n` and `r` to numbers (via [unary plus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15129137/1048572), or use [`parseInt` or something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090518/1048572)):

```
var n = + thisNumber[0];
var r = + thisNumber[1];
```

([Corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AtkVp/2/))