# Why is 1 + '1' = '11' and 1 - '1' = 0 in JavaScript (Coercion)?

Tags: javascript

This seems quite obvious in its logic (a string can't subtract) but I would like to know how this decision is taken in the underlying execution of JavaScript. How exactly are coercion rules being applied here?

Comment: It's all in [the language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/). See sections 11.6.1 (Addition) and 11.6.2 (Subtraction). Notice that the steps are quite different.

Comment: The plus `+` operator is overloaded: when you give it a string (`'1'`) and an int with a `+` sign, it concatenates them (thus you have `11`). It's not possible to do a subtract concatenation, so JavaScript does an actual minus operation, taking both operands to be integers.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`-` is defined in terms of `ToNumber`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2), whereas `+` has an extra [clause for strings](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) (emphasis mine):

> #### 11.6.1 The Addition operator ( `+` )
>
> The addition operator either performs string concatenation or numeric
>   addition.
>
> The production
>
> ```
> AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression +  MultiplicativeExpression
> ```
>
> is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `AdditiveExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `MultiplicativeExpression`.
> 4. Let `rval` be `GetValue(rref)`.
> 5. Let `lprim` be `ToPrimitive(lval)`.
> 6. Let `rprim` be `ToPrimitive(rval)`.
> 7. If `Type(lprim)` is `String` or `Type(rprim)` is `String`, then
>
>    - Return the String that is the result of concatenating `ToString(lprim)` followed by `ToString(rprim)`
>
> [...]

Comment: I prefer the colouring and styles on [**this**](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) copy of the spec for ease-to-read (it's just personal preference) http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1