# How to get value from input element as a number in decimal

Tags: jquery, input, numbers, decimal

I wnat to get values from input elements as numbers and count them with jQuery. I'm trying, but result is not on decimal. How to fix that problem ?

HTML

```
<input name="test1" value="1.77" type="hidden" />
<input name="test2" value="1.23" type="hidden" />
```

jQuery

```
var a = parseInt($( "input[name='test1']").val(), 10);
var b = parseInt($( "input[name='test2']").val(), 10);
alert( a + b ); // should be 3, but it is only 2
```

Here is an example -> 
[**jsfiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/87tdj7z3/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `parseFloat` for decimals and not `parseInt` (which is for integers)!

e.g.

```
var a = parseFloat($( "input[name='test1']").val(), 10);
var b = parseFloat($( "input[name='test2']").val(), 10);
var c = ( a + b );

$('#result').append( c );
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/87tdj7z3/5/

Comment: Thank you very much, it solves the problem... I have one another question. What do you think about this error ? http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/87tdj7z3/7/

Comment: That's a floating point rounding error. You often need to resort to the math library to round numbers to a specific number of decimal places.

Answer (score 5):

the `+` operator is a shortcut to parse numbers including integer and float.

```js
var a = +$("input[name='test1']").val();
var b = +$("input[name='test2']").val();
alert(a + b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="test1" value="1.77" type="hidden" />
<input name="test2" value="1.23" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: If you wanted to sum these numbers would the syntax be `a += +$("input[name='test1']").val()`?

Answer (score 3):

Use parseFloat instead of parseInt as follows

```
var a = parseFloat($("input[name='test1']").val());
var b = parseFloat($("input[name='test2']").val());
alert( a + b );
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4uuL8dk/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
    var a = parseFloat("10") + "<br>";
    var b = parseFloat("10.00") + "<br>";
    var c = parseFloat("10.33") + "<br>";
    var d = parseFloat("34 45 66") + "<br>";
    var e = parseFloat("   60   ") + "<br>";
    var f = parseFloat("40 years") + "<br>";
    var g = parseFloat("He was 40") + "<br>";

    var n = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found I was getting values from inputs via jQuery and calling parseFloat a lot so I created a small jQuery plugin to return an input value as a number, making use of the [plus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript):

```
jQuery.fn.valNum = function () {
    return +(this.val());
};
```