# Why does having a + before a string in JavaScript convert it to an Integer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, types

Why does the following snippet of code convert my variable of type `string` to type `number`?

```js
let stringInteger = '42';
let convertToInteger = +stringInteger;
console.log(typeof convertToInteger)
```

More specifically, why does prefixing `+` to the variable have this effect? Note, I'm asking why not what it does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does = +\_ mean in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

It's the **Unary Plus Operator**.

Your question is answered here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()

Answer (score 1):

It's called a **Unary Plus operator**. It basically tries to convert non-integer variables into integers (ie `+'true'` and `+'false'` can be 1 and 0). You can read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) and you can read more about the differences between this and other ways to parse integers in js [here](https://medium.com/@nikjohn/cast-to-number-in-javascript-using-the-unary-operator-f4ca67c792ce).