# JavaScript more than one plus or minus operator between two operands

Tags: javascript

I don't understand how the below codes works, can some one help me to understand how this works in JavaScript or why this behaviour ?

1. `5 + + + + + + + + + + + + 2` = **7** ( *If there is no space between operator this will give you error.* )
2. `5 + + + + + + + + + + + + - + + 2` = **3**
3. `5 - - - 1` = **4**
4. `5 - - - + 1` = **4**
5. `5 - - - + - - - - - - 1` = **4**
6. `5 - - - + - - - - - - - 1` = **6**.  ( *If I add one more `-` then this 6 will become `4`, adding `-` will again change it from `4` to `6` ... `6` to `4`*)
7. `5 + + + + + + + + + + + + * + + 2` = This will give you error, so that I can not use multiple `*` or `/` in between to numbers.

Please share if there are any other snippets / reference / blog / etc. like this in JavaScript.

*NB : I have tested all these things in google chrome console - version 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit)*

Comment: this is how math works ++ = + , +- = - , -- = +

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

The `+` and `-` symbols are used both as binary **infix operators** (in addition and subtraction) and as unary **prefix operators** (unary plus and unary minus). ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence))

Now, if you have a look at the associativity of the operators, you will note that your expressions are equivalent to the following expressions (with explicit grouping showing the associativity):

- `5 + (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (2))))))))))))`
- `5 + (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (- (+ (+ 2))))))))))))))`
- `5 - (- (- (1)))`
- `5 - (- (- (+ (1))))`
- `5 - (- (- (+ (- (- (- (- (- (- (- 1))))))))))`
- `5 - (- (- (+ (- (- (- (- (- (- (- (1)))))))))))`

```js
console.log('5 + + + + + + + + + + + + 2 === 5 + (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (2)))))))))))): ', 5 + + + + + + + + + + + + 2 === 5 + (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (2)))))))))))));

console.log('5 + + + + + + + + + + + + - + + 2 === 5 + (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (- (+ (+ 2)))))))))))))): ', 5 + + + + + + + + + + + + - + + 2 === 5 + (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (- (+ (+ 2)))))))))))))));

console.log('5 - - - + 1 === 5 - (- (- (+ (1)))): ', 5 - - - + 1 === 5 - (- (- (+ (1)))));

console.log('5 - - - 1 === 5 - (- (- (1))): ', 5 - - - 1 === 5 - (- (- (1))));

console.log('5 - - - + - - - - - - 1 === 5 - (- (- (+ (- (- (- (- (- (- 1))))))))): ', 5 - - - + - - - - - - 1 === 5 - (- (- (+ (- (- (- (- (- (- (1)))))))))));

console.log('5 - - - + - - - - - - - 1 === 5 - (- (- (+ (- (- (- (- (- (- (- (1))))))))))): ', 5 - - - + - - - - - - - 1 === 5 - (- (- (+ (- (- (- (- (- (- (- (1))))))))))));
```

If you remove the spaces (or parens) in between two `+` or `-` symbols you will get the **pre-increment** resp. the **pre-decrement operator** (`++`, `--`) for which the above expressions are not valid.

The last line will result in error because `*` is not a unary prefix operator.

---

**BONUS:** Here's [an article](https://hackernoon.com/js-wtf-with-math-79da9a941ec1) on some weird JS math stuff from a blog series which is aptly titled *JS WTF*. ;-)