# If target value item is in array

Tags: javascript

I have a selection of properties with the div id of property_id that passes an id value. I have an event listener that triggers when a user selects a property. I want to create a conditional that checks if the property selection is in the array.

```
document.getElementById('property_id').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
 var array = [1, 17, 20, 23, 87]
 var propertySelection = e.target.value;
 if (array.includes(propertySelection)) {
   //do stuff
 }
});
```

Doing `console.log(propertySelection)` provides the correct number when selecting properties (ie. 17, 2, 20 etc), but doing `console.log(array.includes(propertySelection))` outputs false on all accounts. Why is this?

Comment: `e.target.value` is a string, you need a number - convert it by doing `Number(e.target.value)`

Comment: Or use this shortcut: `var propertySelection = +e.target.value;`

Comment: Ah. Spot on @VLAZ If you want to create the answer I can accept it.

Comment: `e.target.value` * 1 will also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that input values from the page are always returned as strings:

```js
const val = document.getElementById('property_id').value;

console.log(val, typeof val)
```

```html
<input type="number" value=20 id="property_id" />
```

Which then means that when using `Array#includes()` on an array of numbers, no match can be found:

```js
var array = [1, 17, 20, 23, 87];
var propertySelection = "20";

console.log(array.includes(propertySelection));
```

Instead, the most direct way to get a numeric value from an input is using `.valueAsNumber`

```js
document.getElementById('property_id').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var array = [1, 17, 20, 23, 87]
  var propertySelection = e.target.valueAsNumber;
  // get numeric value directly    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  if (array.includes(propertySelection)) {
    console.log("do stuff");
  } else {
    console.log("don't do anything");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="property_id" />
```

Alternative is using [`Number` as a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Description) to convert a string value to a number:

```js
document.getElementById('property_id').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var array = [1, 17, 20, 23, 87]
  var propertySelection = Number(e.target.value);
  // convert to number    ^^^^^^^              ^
  if (array.includes(propertySelection)) {
    console.log("do stuff");
  } else {
    console.log("don't do anything");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="property_id" />
```

For completeness, the you can also

- [a unary plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript) which is exactly the same as calling `Number`.
- [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) which will do basically the same however `parseFloat("123.4abc")` is `123.4` while `Number("123.4abc")` and `+"123.4abc"` would return `NaN`
- [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) if you prefer only integers.