# what is the meaning of the expression (x = +_, force) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me the meaning of the expression `(x = +_, force)`?
I know that `x` is getting incremented by `_`  but what does `force` separated by comma does?

```
  force.x = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (x = +_, force) : x;
  }
```

is it calling/referencing the function named force?
in the full code force is a function..

Comment: For the `= +_`, [What does = +_ mean in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15129137/215552)

Comment: btw, where is `x` coming from? is it a global variable?

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
(x = +_, force)
```

features the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and return the last expression `force`. In this case as result for assigning.

A better style would be

```
force.x = function(_) {
    if (arguments.length) {
        x = +_;
        return force;
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh.. Nina.... you again... great! ☺️ thanks

Comment: one doubt... what happens when you return force ?? is it getting called or what??

Comment: `force` is never called. the value/reference is returned.

Comment: what is the need of that?

Comment: it's not my code.

Comment: ok. great. thanks  

Comment: is there a way to connect with you please?? I'm a newbie developer.. seems like you know well a lot... I won't trouble you... this is for future help..

Comment: sorry. no way ...

Comment: but why??? is there a reason?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222798/discussion-between-mex-and-nina-scholz).