# Struggling with Number.isInteger()

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment to make a converter from decimal to binary numbers and vice versa. I have done everything I need, but I have no idea how to protect the site from the user entering a number with the part after the decimal point.

So I fooled around the internet and found `Number.isInteger()`, yet I have no idea how this works. Tried writing some test stuff (as you can observe beneath this wall of text) but nothing seemed to work. Can anyone offer any help as to how exactly Number.isInteger() works?

```js
pepege() {
  var a = +document.getElementById("x").value;
  var b = Number.isInteger(a);
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = b;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="x">
<br>
<input type="button" value="xddddd" onclick="pepege();">
<br>
<a id="out"></a>
```

Thanks for any and all advice on how to move forward with this.

Comment: You can test most JS code on the CLI using Node.JS. Write a file `file.js` that you want to execute and run `node file.js` to see the output. It does not work with the DOM though, but you don't need the DOM to figure out what most JS functions do.

Comment: Are you asking how the method works (behind the scenes), or are you asking how to _implement_ it for your case? Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Add `function` before `pepege() {`, then your code will work and display true/false as expected. But I think testing how `Number.isInteger` (or any other function, for that matter) works would be much easier in the devtools console...

Comment: Do a google search for Number.isInteger(), which returns a boolean value. As this is homework I didn't want to give you an precise code answer

Comment: @Leau, please do not make edits that correct code in questions. That masks problems that need to be addressed.

Comment: *What* doesn't work? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener and force user to enter just number. As i understand you are having problem with user inputs

```js
const pepege = () => {
  var a = +document.getElementById("x").value;
  var b = Number.isInteger(a);
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = b;
}

 
document.getElementById("x").addEventListener("input", event => {
  document.getElementById("x").value = document.getElementById("x").value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1')
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="x">
<br>
<input type="button" value="xddddd" onclick="pepege();">
<br>
<a id="out"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your `var a` in `parseFloat()`. Input type text always returns a string. With `parseFloat()`, you'll get NaN for non-numeric characters, a float for a float, and an integer for an integer.

```js
function pepege() {
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("x").value);
  var b = Number.isInteger(a);
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = b;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="x">
<br>
<input type="button" value="xddddd" onclick="pepege();">
<br>
<a id="out"></a>
```

Comment: It's already using [a unary plus that converts to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript). There is no reason to use `parseFloat` unless you believe the input makes a difference. Yet, OP hasn't shared what input they try.

Comment: Add the unary plus and it returns `true` if you enter a number like `1`. My comment is correct.

Comment: @VLAZ No, you're not correct, because the unary plus returns true with floats.

Comment: [feel free to try it](https://jsbin.com/hukixik/1/edit?html,js,output) and enter `1` and press the button then `1.2` and press the button. You'd see the values "true" then "false".

Comment: @VLAZ weird, it wasn't working for me before.