# When is obj.length not equal to +obj.length?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I was perusing the [underscore.js annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) when I encountered this:

```
if (obj.length === +obj.length) {...}
```

I now know from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/javascript-plus-symbol-before-variable) that the plus sign (+) operator returns the numeric representation of the object.

That said, obj.length returns a number. When would `obj.length` not be equal to `+obj.length`?

Comment: it ensures that the length holds an actual number and not a string representing a number.. (*because it uses `===` which checks type as well*). This way it increases protection against passing it a random object that happens to have a `length` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When, for example:

```
var obj = {
    0: 'first',
    length: '1'
};

alert(obj.length === +obj.length);
```

Underscore's `each` is a generic, therefore can work with other objects other than an `array`. Just like ECMA5 [`forEach`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18)

> The forEach function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the forEach function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.

So underscore are checking the validity of an object's `length` property. And they deem an object `arrayLike`, for that method of iteration, only if the object's `length` returns a `number` which is not `NaN`, and is certainly not a `string`. So in my above example, `obj` would fall through to their `keys` iteration, if there is no native/polyfilled `forEach`.

Answer (score 5):

The `===` operator does not make any typecast when it checks, so different types of data will immediately return false even if `'5' == 5`. The `+` as you said typecasts the object into number. If you typecast a number into a number, it is still a number, so you basically check if your `object.length` exists and is a number. Values like `undefined`, `NaN`, `null`, `string` and others will return `false`. You are not sure what happens with obj, so you have to check...

Comment: A number primitive — a number object would cause it to be false.

Comment: a number object is an object, not a number, seriously dude

Comment: Well you *can* do `new Number(num)`, but that's stupid

Comment: that is what gsnedders says, but just `Numer(num)` returns actual number, and not number object