# Replace each digit by (the sum of that digit plus 7) modulus 10

Tags: javascript, modulus

I need to get input from user and replace each digit by (the sum of that digit 
plus 7) modulus 10; however, my formula does not calculate correctly. will you help me to debug?
Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var input = window.prompt("Enter Four-digit numbers:","0000");
    var digits = input.split("");

    var digit1=digits[0];
    var digit2=digits[1];
    var digit3=digits[2];
    var digit4=digits[3];

    digit1=((digit1+7) % 10);
    digit2=((digit2+7) % 10);
    digit3=((digit3+7) % 10);
    digit4=((digit4+7) % 10);

    document.writeln(digit1+"<br/>"+digit2+ "<br/>"+digit3+ "<br/>"+digit4);    
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `split` function returns an array of strings. You cannot do arithmetic operations such as addition and taking modulus on strings, thus you need to convert them to numbers:

```
var digit1 = parseInt(digits[0], 10);
var digit2 = parseInt(digits[1], 10);
var digit3 = parseInt(digits[2], 10);
var digit4 = parseInt(digits[3], 10);
```

Comment: Please always include the `radix` argument when using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: Nikola your solution was my answer, Thank you! do you mind tell me was I had to pars? all was integers??!!

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/Ze9Vu/

```
    digit1=((+digit1+7) % 10);
    digit2=((+digit2+7) % 10);
    digit3=((+digit3+7) % 10);
    digit4=((+digit4+7) % 10);
```

[javascript: plus symbol before variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/javascript-plus-symbol-before-variable)

```
var a = "1";
var b = a;  // b = "1": a string
var c = +a;  // c = 1: a number
var d = -a;  // d = -1: a number
```

Comment: I did, but it is always one digit less, here is the result of 1234 => 8
9
0
1

Comment: @NilRad `1+7%10=8`, `2+7%10=9`, `3+7%10=0` and `4+7%10=1`

Comment: but it suppose to be digit+digit+7 % 10 which is (1+1+7)%10. I just had to pars it first, but since they all are numbers don't know why?

Comment: now it works great, don't know why it doesn't work on mine. Thank you very much :)