# d3.js prepended plus sign

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to Javascript, and I am using d3.js for visualizations. I know about operator meanings and concatenation, and have read that the `+` sign can perform changing the right-hand operand to the `+` sign to a numeric value, however I'm stumped on what the line `gravity = +x;` in `force.gravity` is doing since x is already a numeric value (already an integer). I have tested with negative and positive numbers and it seems to just return the value I pass through the `x`, I do get past the if statement for my uses. Whereas, if I use `-x` then it will change the sign. Can anyone explain what is going on with the `+`&`-` and why the function is basically just returning what I pass.

```
force.gravity = function(x) {
  if (!arguments.length) return gravity;
  gravity = +x;
  return force;
};
```

Comment: `+x` where `x` is a number does exactly what it does when `x` is a string -- convert it to a number. The result of a number converted to a number is that same number.

Comment: Ah, Thank you for the explanation Lars. I guess I was looking into it too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It causes the object passed in, `x`, to be converted to a number. If a string is passed in it will attempt to convert it to a number before setting `gravity`.

For example, calling `force.gravity('1');` will have the same result as calling `force.gravity(1);`.

See [javascript: plus symbol before variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/javascript-plus-symbol-before-variable).

Comment: I posted that I knew that it did that conversion already, and that x is already a numeric value(int not a string). Maybe I should have clarified that part.