# Interpret a cumbersome conditional expression

Tags: javascript

Last night I was looking for an AngularJS snippet to manage a vertical tabs menu and I found this expression:

```
if(+!!variableName)
  doSomething();
```

Sorry, I can't understand what it mean `+!!variableName`
How can I resolve this conditional expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically one way of saying that if the number if not `null` or `undefined`

```
if(+!!variableName)
  doSomething();
```

if `variableName` is `0`,  empty (`""`), `null` or `undefined`, it will translate to `false` or else to `true`.

For example, if

```
var variableName = null;
```

now, this will translate to `(+!!null)` -> `(+!true)` -> `(+false)` -> `false`

similarly, if

```
var variableName = "anything";
```

This will translate to `(+!!"anything")` -> `(+!false)` -> `(+true)` -> `true`

`+` in this case has no effect on the outcome, so can be safely removed.

In fact, whole conditional expression can be replaced by

```
if(variableName)
  doSomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing *cumbersome* in that statement. It's just combination of two operators- Logical Not `!` and Unary plus `+`.

**Evaluation Steps:**

1. `!!`: [Logical Not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)). Cast the variable to Boolean. See [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)
2. `+`: [Unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()). Cast to Number. See [javascript: plus symbol before variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/javascript-plus-symbol-before-variable)

In short, the result will be `1` if the variable is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and `0` if [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Also note that there is no need of unary plus operator here as the Boolean itself is enough in the `if()`.

The above statement can be safely changed to

```
if(!!variableName) // Note `+` is removed.
    doSomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be evaluated like,

say `variableName` is holding `"test"`

1. `!variableName` => `false`
2. `!false` => `true`
3. `+true`  => `1`

This is how that expression will be evaluated.

`!` is a logical not operator, use for negating the values.

`+` is normal arithmetic operator(aka [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) as tushar mentioned), but if you make it preceded by any variable then it will try to convert that variable to a number. If it fails to do that, it will evaluate the expression  to `NaN`