# Solo `+` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I came across some weird JavaScript code:

```
var a, b; // integers set somewhere;

var c = +b;

someFunc(+a);
```

What does that `+` mean here? In my tests I cannot see any effect from it in JavaScript, but at the same time it is valid JavaScript.

What is it really, and why would anyone ever use it?

Comment: [see documentation on unary +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a unary operator. It converts the value to a Number, if it can.

`+'4' === 4`

`+'4.23' === 4.23`

`+'true' === 1`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_operators

Comment: Not just integers.

Comment: You're right, too broad. Edited to number.

Comment: Wow, after years of writing in JavaScript this one escaped me somehow, I always used `* 1` instead :) Thank you!

Comment: It is worth noting that if for some reason the value is undefined let's say `+a`, here `a` is `undefined` it'll return `NaN`.

For more check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64175820/5375291)

Answer (score 2):

It converts the value to a Number