# How to sort javascript object key in ASC

Tags: javascript

I want to sort object keys in ASC .My keys is string and number so try with sort is not solve .

```
//sorting number function
function sortNum(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}
let obj = {key10:10,key2:2,key5:5,key1:1};
let ordered = {};
Object.keys(obj).sort().forEach(function(key,v){
    ordered[key] = v;
});
console.log(ordered); //{key1: 1, key10: 10, key2: 2, key5: 5}
//try with sort number function
//Object.keys(obj).sort(sortNum).forEach(function(key){
//ordered[key] = obj[key];
//});
//console.log(ordered); -> {key10: 10, key2: 2, key5: 5, key1: 1}
```

> Expected =>  `{key1: 1, key2: 2, key5: 5, key10: 10}`

Answer (score 1):

Since they all have the same start (key), sort by comparing the numbers.

I've stored it as an array that you can just use to access the original object.

```js
let obj = {key10:10,key2:2,key5:5,key1:1};
var ordered = Object.keys(obj).sort( (a,b) => {
  let numA = a.match(/\d+/);
  let numB = b.match(/\d+/);
  return +numA - +numB;
});
console.log(ordered);
```

Comment: Is + in return `numA` typo or have any reason for use its ?

Comment: implicitly converts it into a number https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/javascript-plus-symbol-before-variable

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`Array#sort`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwibpuvD-4fUAhVFrJQKHVC3De8QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort&usg=AFQjCNEGi0Cab6xU1_1jrxG44Qu1jxuBXg) sorting with `ASC` order and [`Array#reduce`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi52aK7-4fUAhUBUZQKHco8ANMQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Freduce&usg=AFQjCNHHMuqxJ882tP03jasOvA3-26VV9Q) used for return with object .Finally  `/(\d+)/` used for find the numbers in the key

```js
let obj = {key10:10,key2:2,key5:5,key1:1};
var ordered = Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b)=>{
       return  parseInt(a.match(/(\d+)/)) < parseInt(b.match(/(\d+)/)) ? -1 : parseInt(a.match(/(\d+)/)) > parseInt(b.match(/(\d+)/)) ? 1 :0;
}).reduce((a,b) => (a[b]=obj[b] ,a),{})
console.log(ordered);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) methods to map and reduce your collection in your sorted collection. Read the comments and let me know if you need more clarification!

```js
let obj = {
  key10: 10,
  key2: 2,
  key5: 5,
  key1: 1
};
let ordered = (Object
  // creates an array of keys
  .keys(obj)
  // map each key into a tuples of {key, value} objects
  .map(key => ({
    key,
    value: obj[key]
  }))
  // sort those objects by the value
  .sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)
  // then reduce back into another object
  .reduce((ordered, {key, value}) => {
    ordered[key] = value;
    return ordered;
  }, {})
);


console.log(ordered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use both parts of the string, nonnumerical, sort by string and the numerical part, sort by number with a regular expression.

```js
let obj = { key10: 10, key2: 2, key5: 5, key1: 1, foo1000: 1000, foo0: 0, foo20: 20 },
    keys = Object.keys(obj);

keys.sort(function (a, b) {
    function parts(s) { return s.match(/\D+|\d+/g); }
    var aa = parts(a),
        bb = parts(b);
    return aa[0].localeCompare(bb[0]) || aa[1] - bb[1];
});

console.log(keys);
```