# Remove objects from array based on their property with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the array of objects:

```
var items = [
{"rank":"3","color":"red"},
{"rank":"4","color":"blue"},
{"rank":"0","color":"green"},
{"rank":"6","color":"blue"},
{"rank":"0","color":"yellow"}
];
```

I want to remove all the enries with rank 0, so that the result will be:

Items:

```
[{"rank":"3","color":"red"},
{"rank":"4","color":"blue"},
{"rank":"6","color":"blue"}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a filter to the Items array :

```
items.filter(item => item.rank > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply filter :

```js
var items = [{"rank":"3","color":"red"},{"rank":"4","color":"blue"},{"rank":"0","color":"green"},{"rank":"6","color":"blue"},{"rank":"0","color":"yellow"}];

result = items.filter(({rank})=>rank>0);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.filter method to do that.

```
items = items.filter(i=> {
   return i.rank !== '0';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var items = [
{"rank":"3","color":"red"},
{"rank":"4","color":"blue"},
{"rank":"0","color":"green"},
{"rank":"6","color":"blue"},
{"rank":"0","color":"yellow"}
];

let filteredArray = items.filter(el => el.rank > 0);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to `filter` by `trusy` value and apply `+` sign to convert from `string` to `number`:

```js
var items = [
   {"rank":"3","color":"red"},
   {"rank":"4","color":"blue"},
   {"rank":"0","color":"green"},
   {"rank":"6","color":"blue"},
   {"rank":"0","color":"yellow"}
];

result = items.filter(({rank})=> +rank);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Artemis_ [The + operator returns the numeric representation of the object.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-plus-symbol-before-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

you can apply a  filter like so:

```
items = items.filter(el => el.rank != "0")
```