# Get selected radio button and checkbox decimal value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I take the values from data-attribute and do the calculation using jQuery. But it's not showing the correct values for decimal values. But it is working fine for without decimal values. Can anyone help me out?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#optionfood').on('change', function() {
    update_total();
  });

  function update_total() {
    var tot = 0;
    var price = 0;
    $('#optionfood input:checked').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($(this).data('price')).toFixed(2);
      if (price > 0) {
        tot += price;
      }
    });
    $('#optionfood select').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($("option:selected", this).data('price')).toFixed(2);
      if (price > 0) {
        tot += price;
      }
    });
    $('.modlcstmtotal').html(tot);
  }
  update_total();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="optionfood">
<input type="radio" class="form-radio-input" id="choice1" name="choicemodal" value="20" checked data-price="20.00"><label for="choice1" class="width100">20.00</label>
<input type="radio" class="form-radio-input" id="choice2" name="choicemodal" value="30" data-price="30.00"><label for="choice2" class="width100">30.00</label>

<hr>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1" value="30.00" data-price="30.00"><label for="check1" class="width100">30.00</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check2" value="35.50" data-price="35.50"><label for="check2" class="width100">35.50</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check3" value="45.50" data-price="45.50"><label for="check3" class="width100">45.50</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check4" value="50.00" data-price="50.00"><label for="check4" class="width100">50.00</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check5" value="40.50" data-price="40.50"><label for="check5" class="width100">40.50</label>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>Total is</div><div class="modlcstmtotal"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.toFixed()` returns a string value, `tot += price;` is string concatenation, not addition.

Use `.toFixed()` in output, not in calculations:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#optionfood').on('change', function() {
    update_total();
  });

  function update_total() {
    var tot = 0;
    var price = 0;
    $('#optionfood input:checked').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
      if (price > 0) {
        tot += price;
      }
    });
    $('#optionfood select').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($("option:selected", this).data('price'));
      if (price > 0) {
        tot += price;
      }
    });
    $('.modlcstmtotal').html(tot.toFixed(2));
  }
  update_total();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="optionfood">
<input type="radio" class="form-radio-input" id="choice1" name="choicemodal" value="20" checked data-price="20.00"><label for="choice1" class="width100">20.00</label>
<input type="radio" class="form-radio-input" id="choice2" name="choicemodal" value="30" data-price="30.00"><label for="choice2" class="width100">30.00</label>

<hr>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1" value="30.00" data-price="30.00"><label for="check1" class="width100">30.00</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check2" value="35.50" data-price="35.50"><label for="check2" class="width100">35.50</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check3" value="45.50" data-price="45.50"><label for="check3" class="width100">45.50</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check4" value="50.00" data-price="50.00"><label for="check4" class="width100">50.00</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check5" value="40.50" data-price="40.50"><label for="check5" class="width100">40.50</label>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>Total is</div><div class="modlcstmtotal"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you so much. I also fixed it before seen your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The plus unary operator returns the [numeric representation of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-plus-symbol-before-a-variable). Try adding a plus (+) before the variables (`tot` and `price`):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#optionfood').on('change', function() {
    update_total();
  });

  function update_total() {
    var tot = 0;
    var price = 0;
    $('#optionfood input:checked').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($(this).data('price')).toFixed(2);
      if (price > 0) {
        tot += +price;
      }
    });
    $('#optionfood select').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($("option:selected", this).data('price')).toFixed(2);
      if (price > 0) {
        tot += +price;
      }
    });
    $('.modlcstmtotal').html(tot);
  }
  update_total();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="optionfood">
<input type="radio" class="form-radio-input" id="choice1" name="choicemodal" value="20" checked data-price="20.00"><label for="choice1" class="width100">20.00</label>
<input type="radio" class="form-radio-input" id="choice2" name="choicemodal" value="30" data-price="30.00"><label for="choice2" class="width100">30.00</label>

<hr>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1" value="30.00" data-price="30.00"><label for="check1" class="width100">30.00</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check2" value="35.50" data-price="35.50"><label for="check2" class="width100">35.50</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check3" value="45.50" data-price="45.50"><label for="check3" class="width100">45.50</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check4" value="50.00" data-price="50.00"><label for="check4" class="width100">50.00</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check5" value="40.50" data-price="40.50"><label for="check5" class="width100">40.50</label>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>Total is</div><div class="modlcstmtotal"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#optionfood').on('change', function() {
    update_total();
  });

  function update_total() {
    var tot = 0;
    var price = 0;
    $('#optionfood input:checked').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
      if (price > 0) {      
        tot += +price;
      }
    });
    $('#optionfood select').each(function() {
      price = parseFloat($("option:selected", this).data('price')).toFixed(2);
      if (price > 0) {
        tot += price;
      }
    });
    $('.modlcstmtotal').html(tot.toFixed(2));
  }
  update_total();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="optionfood">
<input type="radio" class="form-radio-input" id="choice1" name="choicemodal" value="20" checked data-price="20.00"><label for="choice1" class="width100">20.00</label>
<input type="radio" class="form-radio-input" id="choice2" name="choicemodal" value="30.5" data-price="30.00"><label for="choice2" class="width100">30.00</label>

<hr>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check1" value="30.00" data-price="30.00"><label for="check1" class="width100">30.00</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check2" value="35.50" data-price="35.50"><label for="check2" class="width100">35.50</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check3" value="45.50" data-price="45.50"><label for="check3" class="width100">45.50</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check4" value="50.00" data-price="50.00"><label for="check4" class="width100">50.00</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="check5" value="40.50" data-price="40.50"><label for="check5" class="width100">40.50</label>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>Total is</div><div class="modlcstmtotal"></div>
```

The price is treated as a `string` when there is no fraction. So I converted the price to number `tot += +price` before doing the summation.