# Hide a value that has 0

Tags: javascript

please tell me how to do in this function so that the value having 0 is not displayed

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.age-count')

elements.forEach(function(el) {
  const count = el.textContent
  const title = declination(count, [' год', ' года', ' лет'])
  const age = count + title

  el.textContent = age
})

function declination(number, titles) {
  cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return titles[(number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[(number % 10 < 5) ? number % 10 : 5]];
}
```

```html
<div class="age-count">22</div>
<div class="age-count">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the element check that it's text is equal to `0`, and if so set it to `display: none`.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.age-count')

elements.forEach(function(el) {
  const count = el.textContent
  
  if (+count === 0)
    el.style.display = 'none';
    
  const title = declination(count, [' год', ' года', ' лет'])
  const age = count + title

  el.textContent = age
})

function declination(number, titles) {
  cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];
  return titles[(number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20) ? 2 : cases[(number % 10 < 5) ? number % 10 : 5]];
}
```

```html
<div class="age-count">22</div>
<div class="age-count">0</div>
```

Note that this still follows the logic to update the text within the element, even though it has been hidden. You can easily amend the logic flow to avoid that, though.

Comment: Is the `+` before the count to transform it into a number?

Comment: @ChenBr yes, that's right. It's a shorthand way of coercing a string to a Number - more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6682997/519413). It would be possible to compare the values as text, but that's rather brittle as it would be broken by any whitespace at the end of the textContent in the HTML.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the information! Appreciate it.