# Caculatiing form values by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to calculate all fields in the form which have the same class (shown below in the code), I have managed to get this to work, I think I may be setting the wrong value types in javascript as its not adding them together correctly. Its adding them on top of each other and not to each other. so instead of 4.00 + 5.50 equalling to 9.50 it would read 04.0005.50.

```
function calculate() {
    var total = 0;
    $('input.calc').each(function() {
        var num = this.value;
        //Number(this.value, 10);
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
            total += num.toFixed(2);
        }
    });

    $("#total").val(total);
}
```

Any help its appreciated, Thanks

Comment: `.toFixed` returns ["A string representation of number"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). You could combine it with [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or [round to the nearest hundredth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968615/rounding-to-the-nearest-hundredth-of-a-decimal-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">

    function calculate() {
        var total = 0;
        $('input.calc').each(function() {
            var num = this.value;
            //Number(this.value, 10);
            if (!isNaN(num)) {
                total += num.parseFloat(num);
            }
        });

        $("#total").val(total);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: This does not do anything, must be an error somewhere. Thanks

Comment: @JohnJ the original code says `parseFloat(num)` as is supposed to. I accepted an edit without reading it, sorry! `:P`

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculate() {
var total = 0;
$('input.calc').each(function() {
 var num = parseFloat(this.value);
                        //Number(this.value, 10);
                        if (!isNaN(num)) {
                            total += num;
                        }
                    });

$("#total").val(total);
}
```