# Javascript how to check if the Quotient is an Integer

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
1.15 / 0.01 = 114.99999999999999, is an Integer in my case
9.96 / 0.01 = 996.0000000000001, is an Integer in my case
15.121 / 0.01 = 1512.1, Not an Integer
```

`Number.isInteger()` is not accurate in cases: `1.15 / 0.01` and `9.96 / 0.01`

Comment: You can't. When you starts with floating point numbers, you must explicitly decide a certain precision to use. There is no "standard" or "correct" way to tell if a floating point number is integer. All depends on the precision you decide to use. You have to round the number to your preferred precision than check again.

Comment: If you want to exceed the precision of `number` type, you may want to look in to libraries like [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/) to handle extra precision.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a dedicated library for this, such as [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/).

Decimal objects have a useful method [isInteger()](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/#isIntisInt()), that can be invoked after the division is complete.

You can set the precision required, though I believe the default should suffice (20, see [precision](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/#precision))

```js
function isQuotientInteger(dividend, divisor) {
    return new Decimal(dividend).dividedBy(new Decimal(divisor)).isInteger();
}

let testInputs = [ { dividend: 1.15, divisor: 0.01 }, { dividend: 9.96, divisor: 0.01 }, { dividend: 15.121, divisor: 0.01 } , { dividend: 3.14159, divisor: 0.00001 }];

formatRow('Dividend', 'Divisor', 'Quotient is integer')
for(let testInput of testInputs) {
    formatRow(testInput.dividend, testInput.divisor, isQuotientInteger(testInput.dividend, testInput.divisor))
}

function formatRow(...row) {
    console.log(...row.map(f => (f + '').padEnd(10)))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/10.3.1/decimal.min.js" integrity="sha512-Ou4M+sSU8oa+mE3juYqR3JmW633MUpMhe1cd+IusOtfjkMo8I3zXs4fRmjmCFqpRg5RK/geqoXBY8XRwFY2Rsg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from this thread:

[Rounding to the nearest hundredth of a decimal in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968615/rounding-to-the-nearest-hundredth-of-a-decimal-in-javascript)

```
let ex1=1.15 / 0.01
let ex2=9.96 / 0.01
let ex3=15.121 / 0.01
const desired_place=3

function round(num, places) {
    //round # to however many places you need
    let multiplier = Math.pow(10, places);
    let rounded= Math.round(num * multiplier) / multiplier;
    return Number.isInteger(rounded)? true : false
}

console.log(round(ex1,desired_place))  //true
console.log(round(ex2,desired_place))  //true
console.log(round(ex3,desired_place))  /false
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript all numbers are internally represented as floating point numbers, which can in many cases lead to visible or invisible rounding issues, when mathematical operations are executed. It is unfortunate that `Number.isInteger()` produces an unexpected result in the cases you list, where we humans can clearly "see" that the result of the operation must be an integer value. Here is a practical solution to find out if a quotient is an integer with a given precision:

First you should use `Number.toFixed()` to get a number rounded to your required precision, and then apply `Number.toInteger()`.

```js
function isInteger(arg) {
  const precision = 12; // for example
  return Number.isInteger(Number(arg.toFixed(precision)));
}

console.log(isInteger(1.15 / 0.01));
console.log(isInteger(9.96 / 0.01));
console.log(isInteger(15.121 / 0.01));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try checking for the remainder.

```
console.log(1.15 % 0.01 === 0) // false
```