# JavaScript in Node: Unexpected behavior for console.timeEnd()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, console.log

I am trying to find the elapsed time in JavaScript. The most common approach suggested is to use `console.time(label)` and `console.timeEnd(label)`.

For example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18427652/5192528

This solution works if I try it on the client-side JavaScript, i.e.

```
console.time('task');

setTimeout(end, 10);

function end() {
  console.timeEnd('task');
}
```

prints

```
finish: 11ms
```

which is the correct time elapsed.

However, when I try the same code in my express app running on Node, I get a different output:

```
finish: 30.714111328125ms
finish: 31.104ms
```

That is, `console.timeEnd('task')` prints both the lines above. So it's printing the start time and end time, which is different from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_timeend_label).

Here's my code and the output in the console.

```
const express = require("express");

let router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getAllPosts);

async function getAllPosts(req, res, next) {

    console.time('finish');

    setTimeout(end, 10);

    function end() {
        console.timeEnd('finish');
    }

    let posts = [];
    res.render("index", {
        posts,
        isLoggedIn: false
    });
}

// Output in Console (in debug mode):

finish: 15.8291015625ms
finish: 16.218ms
```

This is the output when I am not in debug mode:

```
node ./bin/www

express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option 
app.js:24:3
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide 
saveUninitialized option app.js:24:3
app started on http://localhost:3000/
cntr = 1
GET / 304 26.882 ms - -
finish: 26.566ms
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 4.196 ms - -
GET /javascripts/script.js 304 1.367 ms - -
GET /javascripts/file-upload.js 304 2.229 ms - -
GET /favicon.ico 200 3.718 ms - 15086
```

**Note:** both the values are printed on `console.timeEnd()`. I have verified this by stepping through each line, i.e. `console.time` didn't log anything, and `console.timeEnd` logged the output in the console. I am on node version 12.16.1.

**Why am I getting different results for the same code snippet?**

Comment: You don't show where exactly this is in Express, but my guess is that you put it in middleware and that middleware is getting hit by both your web page request and by some other request such as favicon or a script file or an image or something like that.  So, it's printing twice because your server is getting two requests.  If you log `req.url` at the same time, it may reveal why you're getting called twice.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the sample code and the output. I believe it's not getting two requests, as while debugging, the breakpoints only get hit once, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Please don't post code as images.  It makes it impossible to copy that code into our own test app or into an answer, thus making it difficult for people to write you a good answer.  Code should be pasted as text and formatted appropriately.

Comment: Sounds good, I will update the question. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is an issue with using Visual Studio Code in the Debug mode.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38376

and <strike>something I have to live with till VS Code team decides to do something about it.</strike>

I have opened [a new issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93625) on VS Code's Github repository that details the  steps to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Hmmm.  Interesting find.  That first bug was closed as "as-designed".

Answer (score 0):

Well, there has to be something else going on in parts of your code that you don't show us because if I make your code into a working app by just adding three more lines at the end like this and changing the `res.render()` to a `res.send()` so we don't have to have a template and template engine configured (for simplicity of the example):

```
const express = require("express");

let router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getAllPosts);

async function getAllPosts(req, res, next) {

    console.time('finish');

    setTimeout(end, 10);

    function end() {
        console.timeEnd('finish');
    }

    let posts = [];
    res.send("hello");
}

const app = express();
app.use(router);
app.listen(80);
```

And, then I request `http://localhost` in the browser, this is all I see in the server console:

```
finish: 11.708ms
```

There's **just one** of them.

So, something else in the code you don't show us is apparently causing your issue.  I am wondering what's in `index.html`?  Is there by any chance an Ajax call to `/` or any other resource requests in that HTML file?

Apparently, there is something else that is making another request to your server.  I'd suggest you instrument that route like I show below to just prove that the route is getting called twice:

```
const express = require("express");

let router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getAllPosts);

let cntr = 1;                                        // add this
async function getAllPosts(req, res, next) {

    console.log(`cntr = ${cntr++}`);                 // add this

    console.time('finish');

    setTimeout(end, 10);

    function end() {
        console.timeEnd('finish');
    }

    let posts = [];
    res.send("hello");
}

const app = express();
app.use(router);
app.listen(80);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried your code snippet, and the counter only printed once. So the method is definitely getting executed once per request. However, I noticed that if I launch the site without debugging, I get a 304 redirect status code, just before the log prints the time. Maybe that has anything to do with this? I have updated my question to add the complete log output. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @AkshayKhot - I don't know what you mean by the new log.  There's only one "finish" line there.  The 304 status has to do with caching.  If you cleared your browser cache or disabled caching, you wouldn't get that.

Comment: Right, I reloaded the page with devtools open, and it gave the same output, with 200 code.

Comment: The problem turns out to be in the `www` file that `express-generator` set up for me. I still don't understand why it's happening, though. I have posted an answer explaining the cause.

Answer (score 0):

After removing all my extraneous code line by line, I finally figured out the cause, without the understanding. If anyone can explain why it's happening, I will mark it as the answer.

The problem turns out to be in my `bin/www` file, which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require("../app");

app.listen(3000);
```

I set up the app using `express-generator`, which use `bin\www` JavaScript file to configure the app.

```
// app.js

var express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.use("/", function getAllPosts(req, res, next) {

  console.time('finish');

  setTimeout(end, 10);

  function end() {
      console.timeEnd('finish');
  }

  res.send("hello");
});

module.exports = app;
```

If I run the app without using `www`, `console.timeEnd()` works as expected.

For example, this code works fine:

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.use("/", function getAllPosts(req, res, next) {

  console.time('finish');

  setTimeout(end, 10);

  function end() {
      console.timeEnd('finish');
  }

  res.send("hello");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: My only guess is that `var app = require("../app");` isn't loading the right `app.js`.  Otherwise, there's no difference.

Comment: I believe it's loading the correct app.js, as all my routers and other variables defined in `app.js` work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to demonstrate both of your outcomes from the answer you posted.

The issue is that you're using `.use()` instead of `.get()` in your route definition:

```
app.use("/", function getAllPosts(req, res, next) {...}
```

When you use `app.use("/", ...)`, that will match ALL possible routes.  So, when you first do the `www` version, you will get two requests from the browser:

```
/
/favicon.ico
```

Both of those will match `app.use("/", ...)`.  `.use()` matches any route that starts with what you specify.

---

Then, when you remove the www file from the equation, you're still executing the exact same code EXCEPT that the browser has cached the fact that there's no favicon.ico so it doesn't request it.  If you do a shift reload on the single file version, it shows the same problem because the browser again requests the favicon.ico and you get two requests.

---

Change this:

```
app.use("/", function getAllPosts(req, res, next) {...}
```

to:

```
app.get("/", function getAllPosts(req, res, next) {...}
```

and this particular problem goes away in the code you show in your 2nd answer.  I don't know why you changed this route to `app.use()` because you used to have it as `app.get()`.  This was clear to me when I added  this:

```
console.log("in route", req.url);
```

to the start of the route handler.  That's where I clearly saw the `/favicon.ico` request causing the extra output.

Comment: I changed from `app.use()` to `app.get()` and still got the log twice(which is what I had originally, as you mention). However, I noticed that it's only happened in the debug mode. I am not seeing the log twice when I start the app using `npm start` (doesn't matter if it's `use` or `get`). It only prints it once. That's really strange as I did see it twice last night, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I also notice this behavior in debug mode with `app.get/post()`even if I remove the favicon entirely.

Comment: Figured it out, finally. Looks like a side-effect of running VS Code in debug mode. Please see my new answer. Thank you for taking your time to look into this.