# Azure Data Factory - updating Node to 20 in Azure Devops pipeline fails with: The "this" argument must be an instance of Performance

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline created according to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements
I tried to update Node version to 20.x:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '20.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```

and inside package.json

```
 "dependencies":{
        "@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities":"^1.0.0"
    }
```

During validate stage I am getting error:
YAML

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "this" argument must be an instance of Performance. Received an instance of Object
    at now (node:internal/perf/performance:139:5)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue is that a Node.js update broke the `now()` API. Previously as of Node 16 you could do:

```
const now = perf_hooks.performance.now
const t0 = now()
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
  ;
console.log((now() - t0)/1000.0)
```

But tested as of Node v18.13.0 that blows up with:

```
/home/ciro/main.js:1
const now = perf_hooks.performance.now
            ^

ReferenceError: perf_hooks is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ciro/main.js:1:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.13.0
```

A working alternative that maintains the old API in the bulk of the code is:

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks')
const now = performance.now.bind(performance)
const t0 = now()
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
  ;
console.log((now() - t0)/1000.0)
```

If this comes from some dependency you don't control the source of, the choices are either:

- try to update the dependency in the hope that the devs fixed it already
- downgrade your Node.js. Not ideal.

Other timing methods are described at: [How do I measure the execution time of JavaScript code with callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617070/how-do-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-javascript-code-with-callbacks)