# Understanding d3.js source: stuck at function.call() and "=+"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reverse-engineering, force-layout

In the source code of d3.layout.force, line 158, there is this code

```
force.charge = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return charge;
    charge = typeof x === "function" ? x : +x;
    return force;
};
```

Now, if you go to line 225, you will see

```
charges = [];
if (typeof charge === "function") {
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    charges[i] = +charge.call(this, nodes[i], i);
  }
} else {
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    charges[i] = charge;
  }
}
```

What I did not understand here is the line

```
charges[i] = +charge.call(this, nodes[i], i);
```

I am new to JavaScript and can not understand what's going on here.

As far as I understood charge takes only 1 argument (`x`). Here "`this`" is passed to give the context of current object but what about the other two? Which one of "`nodes[i]`" and "`i`" is taken as "`x`" ?

Again what is "`= +`" doing here?

Comment: There's another "charge" function somewhere, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow `charge` more carefully. It is variable defined in [line 11](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/v2.9.2/src/layout/force.js#L11):

```
charge = -30,
```

The function `force.charge` which you quoted is for **setting** the charge, it is **not** the function referred to in `+charge.call(this, nodes[i], i);`.  Have a look at the second line of `force.charge`:

```
charge = typeof x === "function" ? x : +x;
```

`x` can be a function (callback) *you* pass, to dynamically calculate the charge. The current node (`nodes[i]`) and the index of the node (`i`) will be passed to this callback, so that you can calculate the charge dynamically based on these values:

```
force.charge(function(node, index) {
    return index * 2;
});
```

`x` (and therefore `charge`) can also be a number or numerical string. That's why it is tested beforehand whether `charge` is a function or not:

```
if (typeof charge === "function") {
  // function so we call it and pass the current node and index
} else {
  // static value, the same for each node
}
```

---

Apert from that, you can always pass any number of arguments to a function, no matter how many parameters it has defined. For example:

```
function foo() {
    alert([].join.call(null, arguments));
}

foo('a', 'b');
```

will alert `a,b`.

---

To answer your questions: The arguments passed to [`.call()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) are passed in the same order to the function. So if I have a function `function foo(a, b, c)` then `foo.call(null, x, y)` would pass `x` as `a` and `y` as `b` (`c` would be `undefined`).

The `+` operator is the [*unary plus* operator *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29), which simply converts the operand into a number.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the MDN listings for [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

It's a tough concept to wrap your head around but what's happening in call and apply is that you're choosing to execute a function in a different "context."

I say "context" with quotes as "execution context" has an exact meaning in JS and this isn't it. I don't have a great word for it but what's happening here is that you're making swapping out the `this` object when executing the function.

This might help:

```
var obj = { foo: "bar" };
method.call( obj, "arg" );
function method( arg ) {
    console.log( this.foo ); #bar
    console.log( arg ); #"arg"
}
```

Comment: well thanks for answering but as I mentioned that I undertand that "this" is given for passing the context of current object. I have little idea about how call, apply and bind works but I cant understand what the other two parameters ( as function charge takes only one argument ) doing there?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-return-new-date).

Basically, it's converting this:

```
function(){ return +new Date; }
```

into this:

```
function(){ return Number(new Date); }
```

Essentially, it is converting the argument into a number, and adding it to the previous value.

More reading about this [here](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/)

Comment: Glad I could help!  Make sure to accept an answer if it answers your question. :)