# Why the leading `+` in `j = +i + ( i < 0 ? len : 0 )` (taken from jQuery source code)

Tags: javascript

I found the following snippet in the jQuery source code, in the definition of the `eq` function:

```
j = +i + ( i < 0 ? len : 0 )
```

I was surprised by the `+i`. Rather, I would have expected:

```
j = i + ( i < 0 ? len : 0 )
```

What's the difference? What the utility of that leading `+`?

Comment: To cast to a number .

Comment: Oh... I used to use `0+x`... It seems that `+x` is sufficient :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does = +\_ mean in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript) and possibly also [Whats the significant use of Unary Plus and Minus operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators)

Comment: @anishsane: Not only is `+x` sufficient, but in fact, `0+x` won't generally work, since `+` can perform string concatenation as well as addition. For example, `0+'30'` is `'030'`, and `0+{}` is `'0[object Object]'`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The plus in front of the variable casts it to a number.

For example:

```
var x = "12";
console.log(x + 3); //logs 123;
console.log(+x + 3) //logs 15;
```

Comment: Reason number NaN not to use a dynamically-typed language

Comment: There are pro's and con's. Just learn the differences and there will be 0 reasons not to.

Comment: Ahhh the joy of JavaScript,  where any typo is syntactically correct

Answer (score 43):

`+i` coerces to number.  As an example, try `"1" + 1` versus `+"1" + 1` (the former is `"11"` while the latter is `2`)

Comment: Solid, easy to understand explanation. +1

Answer (score 5):

I think it's the unary operator:  [What does the plus sign do in '+new Date'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-return-new-date)

Basically forced it to be converted to a number.