# what is the difference between new Date and +new Date?

Tags: javascript, date

What is the difference between `new Date` and `+new Date`?

For example:

```
var date = new Date;
console.log(date);

var plusDate = +new Date;
console.log(plusDate);
```

Logs:

```
Sat May 10 2014 01:13:46 GMT+0300 (Jordan Standard Time)
1399673626539
```

Comment: Looks like this question has been asked:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-return-new-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [unary plus operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) casts the `Date` object to a `Number` object (which is [expressed in in milliseconds since 01 January, 1970 UTC](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1)).

Comment: +1 - Does it implicitly call `.value`? Does date do the conversion internally or is it done somewhere else?

Comment: @TravisJ—it's all [*in the spec*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6).

Comment: @RobG - Where in the spec does it mention calling .valueOf()? Because that is actually what seems to happen implicitly. http://jsfiddle.net/gcaFu/

Comment: @RobG - I see, "ToNumber(GetValue(expr))" calls GetValue, which "let getter be desc.[[Get]]" for the `expr` in which case `.valueOf()` is called. Date overrides object.prototype.valueOf and returns its time value. Thanks for the links :)

Answer (score -2):

The first one creates a Date object, the second one adds the current date value in milliseconds to the original value of `plusDate`, which was 0.

Comment: Nope. The unary + just merely casts the date to a number.

Comment: Correct. My dyslexia.