# + operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I've noticed that the result of

```
(new Date())
```

is a Date object; in this case

```
Date {Thu Dec 04 2014 22:43:07 GMT+0200 (SAST)}
```

but if I type

```
+(new Date())
```

I get an int value;

```
1417725787989
```

How is this done?

I have a function called 'Duration' which, when used like this:

```
new Duration(352510921)
```

returns an instance looking like this:

```
{ days:5, hours:3, mins:55, secs:10, ms:921 }
```

So how can I use the + operator to get the int value of the Duration instance?

```
var dur = new Duration(352510921);
console.log(+dur) // prints int value 352510921
```

Comment: you can use `valueOf`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-return-new-date

Comment: @rfornal That is not a string...wrong info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unary `+` operator casts the instance to a `Number` in the same way that calling the `Number()` function will cast a variable to a `Number`.

If you'd like to override how your specific instance is cast, you need to override the `valueOf` property for that instance:

```
var a = {
    valueOf: function () {
        return 5;
    }
};
console.log(a); //Object { valueOf: function () {...} }
console.log(+a); //5
```

From the [ES5 standard](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.6):

> ## 11.4.6 Unary + Operator # Ⓣ Ⓡ Ⓖ
>
> The unary + operator converts its operand to Number type.
>
> The production UnaryExpression : + UnaryExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Return [ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3)([GetValue](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1)(expr)).

`ToNumber` on an Object will then result in a [`ToPrimitive`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1) with hint Number. `ToPrimitive` will then call the [`[[DefaultValue]]`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8) internal method which states:

> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with hint Number, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let valueOf be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "valueOf".
> 2. If IsCallable(valueOf) is true then,
>
>    1. Let val be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of valueOf, with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
>    2. If val is a primitive value, return val.
> 3. Let toString be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "toString".
> 4. If IsCallable(toString) is true then,
>
>    1. Let str be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of toString, with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
>    2. If str is a primitive value, return str.
> 5. Throw a TypeError exception.

Comment: Thanks so much, that means I could add a 'toString' function property to my 'Duration' definition and by using:
`'' + new Duration(352510921);`
I could have it print out 
`5 days, 3 hours, 55 minutes, 10 seconds and 921 milliseconds`

Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You can override `valueOf`.

```
> var foo = { days:5, hours:3, mins:55, secs:10, ms:921, valueOf: function() { return 1; }  }   
undefined
> -foo
-1
```