# Grunt match regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to pull the latest revision number using a regular expression that is not working. Could someone helped a novice regexer with this:

`revision: 2020`

`stdout.match(/^r(\d+)/m)[1])`

Thank you for any help you can give

EDIT

I should have put my whole task here so all would know what I am trying to do.

`grunt.registerTask('version', 'Updating to latest revision',
        function () {
            var done = this.async();
            grunt.util.spawn({
                cmd: 'svn info',
                args: ['-r HEAD']
            }, function (err, result, code) {
                var output = result.stdout;
                if (output) {
                    var revision = result.stdout.match(/\d+/)[0];
                    grunt.file.write('web/version2.js', 'var UIVERSION = ' + revision);
                }
                done();
            });
        }
    );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do `\d+`, and then pull the first element, like:

```
var str = 'revision: 2020';
var regex = /\d+/
var number = str.match(regex)[0]; // '2020'
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hg8g6oz7/1/)

And if you want it as an integer rather than a string, just add a `+` to the expression:

```
var number = +str.match(regex)[0]; // 2020
```

Comment: thank you for the demo. I  a sorry that I had to edit my question so it is clearer what I am trying to solve

Comment: @pertrai1, your edit didn't make it clearer for me. Are you saying that my code doesn't work. I see you've added it to that Grunt task. Is there still an outstanding issue?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake on my end. Thank you

Comment: Don't know if you would be willing to take the time in this comment section, what exactly does putting the '+' in front of str do? What is that called so I can research it? Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: It just coerces what was a string into an integer. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-return-new-date).