# JavaScript compare two time variables

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have d1 and d2 set in hour:minute:seconds format... How can I compare two time variables and if first is greater execute the function.

In short.

```
if(d1>d2)
{
//run function
}
```

Comment: Convert to timestamp and then compare.

Comment: Have you tried that? Whether you're working with Date instances or strings, your code should work fine.

Comment: Convert them to timestamps using `+new Date(date here)` and then compare them.

Comment: If they’re zero-padded (always the same length), you can do `if (d1 > d2)`. If not, I’d split them by `:` and compare each part.

Comment: @Tushar, Wow! How does it convert into `timestamps` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre [What does the plus sign do in '+new Date'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-new-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212305/how-can-i-compare-two-time-strings-in-the-format-hhmmss)

```
Date.parse('01/01/2011 10:20:45') > Date.parse('01/01/2011 5:10:10')
```