# Flow type, What does the `+` symbol mean in front a property?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I came across the following code written in js FlowType (I am interested to know the value of + in the context of FlowType not in general JS).

Could you please explain me what does the `+` symbol mean in front of the property in the code below:

```
  export type User = {
      +name: string,
      +surname: string,
      +personId: PourceId,
    }
```

I could not find any reference in the documentation, any link is also welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the plus sign do in '+new Date'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-new-date)

Comment: Not a duplicate, it's something specific to Flowtype.

Comment: Correct, it is not a duplicate I am interested in the + in Flowtype context.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `+` symbol in front of the property means the property is **read-only**

Reference: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only

Answer (score 13):

The '**+**' symbol means the property is **read only** and
'**-**' means the property is **write only** and 
If does not have any **'+'** or **'-'** symbol it means the property have both **read/write** access.
 It can be used while defining interface property or type property.

The documentation can be found in below link:
https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only

Answer (score 5):

After some additional research I found out that `+/-` indicate the covariant or  contravariant for a property.

```
interface MyInterface {
  +covariant: number;     // read-only
  -contravariant: number; // write-only
}
```

Interesting article on variance:

https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/

https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only