# Javascript +new Date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have found this piece of code in a project I am working on:

```
+new Date(DateTime)
```

Note the `+` before new. If I pass in this value:

```
'2020-09-15T01:00:00Z'
```

It outputs this value:

```
1600131600000
```

Can anyone explain to me what this value is? It is not unix time - or at least the unix time moment outputs:

```
moment().unix(DateTime) = 1531737560
```

I am cleaning up my date formats within the project and cannot work out how to recreate this with moment...

EDIT:

How can I recreate this in moment.js?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-new-date

Comment: P.S. your momentJS code makes no sense. Try `moment(DateTime).unix()`. You want to _output_ the unix timestamp, not try and _parse_ `DateTime` as if it were already a timestamp. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/ And even if it _were_ a timestamp you were trying to parse, the code would in any case be moment.unix(timestamp) (as per the docs http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/). So what you wrote is incorrect in both interpretations. Check the docs more carefully.

Comment: *"It is not unix time..."* It is, it's just in milliseconds rather than seconds. *"How can I recreate this in moment.js?"* Probably the simplest way is to get the JavaScript date from it, and use its `getTime`: `yourMomentInstance.toDate().getTime()` (or `+yourMomentInstance.toDate()`). If you want "now" (what `+new Date()` does), use `Date.now` or `moment.now`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder if you write that as the answer I will accept it

Comment: @Alex there's a much simpler way than that to get the equivalent output...momentJS provides .unix() and .valueOf() methods depending on if you want seconds or milliseconds. See my comment above (although I forgot about the valueOf() bit). See also http://jsfiddle.net/svqrxpt0/5/ P.S. your question has been marked duplicate (based on the original edit, I assume) so no answers can be posted unless it's voted to be re-opened

Comment: @ADyson - Ah, good, I was wondering why I couldn't find a "milliseconds since The Epoch" accessor in Moment! `valueOf`. Good to know.