# What does a `+` in front of a Date do?

Tags: javascript, date

I found some code from a departed colleague and no one is sure what the plus in front of the following `Date` objects is doing.

```
return {
  isActive: +new Date(notice.reportedAt) === +this.activeNoticeReportedAt,
  ...
}
```

I feel like it is some kind of JavaScript trick that is supposed to protect against undefined, but that is just a wild guess.

Please not that `activeNoticeReportedAt` is already a `Date`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-new-date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns it into a `number`, which represents the date's Unix timestamp in milliseconds:

```
> +new Date()
< 1542726854220
```

The reason for using it here is that `Date` objects can't be compared using the `==` operator, because that only checks for object equality, not value equality:

```
> x = new Date("2017-01-01")
> y = new Date("2017-01-01")
> x == y
false
```