# How to get the current date or/and time in seconds

Tags: javascript, datetime

How do I get the current date or/and time in seconds using Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Comment: Be aware that the accepted answer will produce a floating-point number.

Answer (score 581, accepted):

```
var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

....will give you the seconds since midnight, 1 Jan 1970

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: @sje397 - Yes...but the question (like most on SO) is most likely to solve a *practical* problem, can you give me an example where you'd want to display this result?

Comment: @Nick - I think all examples are necessarily speculative and will sound contrived - but I'll take a shot :) Suppose you have data time stamped with unix time, and want to determine it's age. More though I think this is what is most likely meant by 'the current date/time in seconds'; just my gut feeling.

Comment: An application where I needed this was to work with a PHP back end as the time() function already returns this. It's also great for a time stamp as you can easily get the difference between time() being our current time and a time stamp from a previous time that had been stored in a database say when a user posted something. In the event you'd like to get a formatted time like 'October 22nd, 2015' you can craft your own function to return that from a timestamp as an argument or use one already here at Stack. Anyways, hope that gives you some insight as to when this would be useful. @NickCraver

Comment: It's worth noting that you want to wrap that in Math.floor(), else you get a decimal.

Comment: One way this would be useful would be calculating the time elapsed between two times.

Comment: Useful if you are going to send the timestamp to a PHP function which expects timestamps to be in seconds rather than milliseconds.

Comment: @Nick I'm using it in my game development to find the length of time it takes to complete a level.

Comment: It would be useful in pretty much any elapsed time measurement with second-granularity that doesn't overflow. So like, in a lot of places.

Comment: Stackoverflow api spits out the post date in seconds, whatever these guys had in mind;) BTW, you can omit `gettime()`.

Comment: Depengin on your needs, you might want to wrap it with Math.round( ... ) or you'll get a floating point number.

Comment: @NickCraver when you want to store that in a database. it would require a Int64 64bits / 8 bytes of data per entry -- `BIGINT`. without it we can still use Int32 `INT` (average use case) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Very useful in video games or any other apps where we need to get seconds elapsed quickly. We can simply store these timestamps as normal integer in our database; since we don't need the Date Time anyway.

Comment: To add the historical context (and maybe this is just me being a cranky old C developer writing modern javascript) time since the epoc is how times have been recorded and calculated in software going back to the beginning of code.  Being able to get a value as seconds or milliseconds that have passed since some set moment long ago is actually an incredibly handy (and efficient) way of calculating differences in time. And recording timestamps. It's much faster to compare integers than to do string processing.  And this is how many (perhaps most) systems still do it under the hood.

Comment: @NickCraver could be useful when you need seconds of "now" instead of microseconds. For example for JWT claim "iat" (issuedAt), where standards specify the value MUST be in seconds from epoch. So here is one usecase

Answer (score 131):

```
 Date.now()
```

gives milliseconds since epoch. No need to use `new`.

Check out the reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

(Not supported in IE8.)

Comment: This answer for milliseconds doesn't even answer the question that was asked. "How do I get the current date/time in seconds"

Comment: `Date.now() / 1000` to answer the question itself

Comment: @magician11 - `Date.now() / 1000` also does not answer the question, because it gives values with partial fractions in milliseconds

Comment: Math.floor(Date.now()/1000)

Answer (score 129):

Using `new Date().getTime() / 1000` is an incomplete solution for obtaining the seconds, because it produces timestamps with floating-point units:

```js
new Date() / 1000; // 1405792936.933

// Technically, .933 would be in milliseconds
```

Which may cause unwanted results in conditional statements:

```
if (1405792936.993 < 1405792937) // true
```

Instead use:

```js
Math.round(Date.now() / 1000); // 1405792937

// Or
Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // 1405792936

// Or
Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000); // 1405792937

// Note: In general, I recommend `Math.round()`,
//   but there are use cases where
//   `Math.floor()` and `Math.ceil()`
//   might be better suited.
```

**Warning:** Bitwise operators could be used to truncate floating-point units, but can also cause issues when working with timestamps. For example, the following bitwise expression `(new Date() / 1000) | 0`, is less preferred than `Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)`, because it causes the following issues:

1. By default Javascript numbers are type 64 bit (double precision) floats, and bitwise operators implicitly convert that type into signed 32 bit integers. Arguably, the type should not be implicitly converted by the compiler, but instead explicitly converted by the developer in code.
2. The signed 32 bit integer timestamp produced by the bitwise operator, causes the [year 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) problem as noted in the comments.

Comment: Totally agree  Use `Math.round(new Date() / 1000)`

Comment: Note that flooring with the bitwise operator will result in the value being converted to a signed 32 bit integer. See [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: @Ryan - thanks I've updated my answer to discourage the use of `| 0`

Comment: why `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor`/`Math.trunc`?

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo - `Math.round()` gives you a more accurate timestamp than `Math.floor()`, or `Math.trunc()`. Let's say `new Date() / 1000` gives you a timestamp of 1405792936.999, which is almost the same as 1405792937. Flooring (and truncating) would give you 1405792936, but rounding would give you 1405792937.

Comment: I don't believe that should apply for date time in general. For example: the 1st second (Jan 1 1970 00:00:000) will never be treated as a whole second, but as a half-second.  A purchase made at last day of a promotion day at 11:59:59.500 PM is not eligible anymore because it will round up, and consider that it's done wrongly the next day.  Do the same for hours and we'll have New Year at 11:30pm: `new Date(Math.round(new Date('2021-12-31 23:30:00')/ (3600 * 1000))*3600*1000)`

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo - Thank you for these examples. The solution I've provided was for the question "How do I get the current date/time in seconds in Javascript?", so your example in hours is not within context, but I do think your examples in seconds have some validity. In general, I still think `Math.round()` is best. But yes, I agree there are use cases where it's not best, and `Math.floor()` and `Math.ceil()` are more appropriate. I've updated my answer to note the same.

Answer (score 37):

Based on your comment, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
var timeout = new Date().getTime() + 15*60*1000; //add 15 minutes;
```

Then in your check, you're checking:

```
if(new Date().getTime() > timeout) {
  alert("Session has expired");
}
```

Answer (score 15):

To get the number of seconds from the Javascript epoch use:

```
date = new Date();
milliseconds = date.getTime();
seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
```

Answer (score 13):

```js
// The Current Unix Timestamp
// 1443535752 seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC)

// Current time in seconds
console.log(Math.floor(new Date().valueOf() / 1000));  // 1443535752
console.log(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000));            // 1443535752
console.log(Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000));  // 1443535752
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery**

```js
console.log(Math.floor($.now() / 1000));               // 1443535752
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

I use this:

```
Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)
```

No need for new object creation (see [doc Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now))

Answer (score 5):

These JavaScript solutions give you the milliseconds or the seconds since the midnight, January 1st, 1970.

The IE 9+ solution(IE 8 or the older version doesn't support this.):

```
var timestampInMilliseconds = Date.now();
var timestampInSeconds = Date.now() / 1000; // A float value; not an integer.
    timestampInSeconds = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Floor it to get the seconds.
    timestampInSeconds = Date.now() / 1000 | 0; // Also you can do floor it like this.
    timestampInSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000); // Round it to get the seconds.
```

To get more information about `Date.now()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

The generic solution:

```
// ‘+’ operator makes the operand numeric.
// And ‘new’ operator can be used without the arguments ‘(……)’.
var timestampInMilliseconds = +new Date;
var timestampInSeconds = +new Date / 1000; // A float value; not an intger.
    timestampInSeconds = Math.floor(+new Date / 1000); // Floor it to get the seconds.
    timestampInSeconds = +new Date / 1000 | 0; // Also you can do floor it like this.
    timestampInSeconds = Math.round(+new Date / 1000); // Round it to get the seconds.
```

Be careful to use, if you don't want something like this case.

```
if(1000000 < Math.round(1000000.2)) // false.
```

Comment: Hi, younger me. How are you doing?

Answer (score 5):

There is **no need to initialize a variable to contain the Date object** because `Date.now()` is a **static method** which means that is accessible directly from an API object's constructor.

### So you can just do this

```js
const ms = Date.now()
const sec = Math.round(ms/1000)
  
document.write(`seconds: ${sec}`)
```

### Something fun

Live update of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC

```js
const element = document.getElementById('root')

setInterval(() => {
  let seconds = Math.round(Date.now()/1000)
  element.innerHTML = seconds
},1000)
```

```html
Seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC 
<h1 id='root'></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Date.now()-Math.floor(Date.now()/1000/60/60/24)*24*60*60*1000
```

This should give you the milliseconds from the beginning of the day.

```
(Date.now()-Math.floor(Date.now()/1000/60/60/24)*24*60*60*1000)/1000
```

This should give you seconds.

```
(Date.now()-(Date.now()/1000/60/60/24|0)*24*60*60*1000)/1000
```

Same as previous except uses a bitwise operator to floor the amount of days.

Answer (score 1):

You can met another way to get time in seconds/milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970:

```
var milliseconds = +new Date;        
var seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
```

But be careful with such approach, cause it might be tricky to read and understand it.

Comment: I do not know since when using language's side effects is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

Better short cuts:

```
+new Date # Milliseconds since Linux epoch
+new Date / 1000 # Seconds since Linux epoch
Math.round(+new Date / 1000) #Seconds without decimals since Linux epoch
```

Answer (score 1):

On some day in 2020, inside Chrome 80.0.3987.132, this gives `1584533105`

```
~~(new Date()/1000) // 1584533105
Number.isInteger(~~(new Date()/1000)) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

To get today's total seconds of the day:

```
getTodaysTotalSeconds(){
    let date = new Date();        
    return +(date.getHours() * 60 * 60) + (date.getMinutes() * 60) + date.getSeconds();
}
```

I have add `+` in return which return in `int`. This may help to other developers. :)

Answer (score -1):

if you simply need seconds in THREE JS, use one of the code bellow in function uses  window.requestAnimationFrame()

`let sec = parseInt(Date.now().toString()[10]); console.log(' counting Seconds => '+ sec );`

or
`let currentTime= Date.now();`

`let secAsString= time.toString()[10];`

`let sec = parseInt(t);`

`console.log('counting Seconds =>'+ sec );`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

A simple and quick way, without creating a date object and giving an integer as result (APIs accepting seconds will error if sending decimal)

```js
var nowInSeconds = ~~(Date.now() / 1000);
console.log(nowInSeconds);
```