# How can I convert the (fractional) result of `new Date().getTime() / 1000` into a whole number?

Tags: javascript, object, date, time

According to this: [Get current date/time in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830244/javascript-get-current-date-time-in-seconds)

`var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;` gives you the time in seconds. But the time given is a decimal number. How can I turn it into whole number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do `Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)` or a short (and faster version):

```
new Date().getTime() / 1000 | 0
```

Using this binary operator will zero the floating number part of your number (and therefore round it down).

Answer (score 2):

Call `Math.round`.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest and simplest:
Force date to be represented as number by made math operation directly on date object.
Parentheses can be ommited where we calling to constructor without arguments

```
new Date/1000|0  // => 1326184656

+new Date == new Date().getTime() // true
```

Explanation:

```
new Date // => Tue Jan 10 2012 09:22:22 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
```

By apply `+` operator

```
+new Date //=> 1326184009580
```

Answer (score 1):

Round it.

```
console.log(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
// 1326051145.787
console.log(Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));
// 1326051146
```

Basic maths!

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know of Math.round.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Google was registered in 1998.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Oh, you again. Here I was thinking your attitude on your first comment above was a once-off.

Comment: @gotnull: Pot, meet kettle. At least I'm trying to teach this OP to do research which will _indisputably help him_ as a skill. You're just writing comments to attack my character.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Kettle, meet pot. Patronising someone doesn't help at all. I agree with teaching people (OP in this case) to do research, however telling them that Google was registered in 1998 isn't helping at all IMO. Each to their own I guess.

Comment: @gotnull Yes it is. It's bringing the term Google into the conversation. Are you going to stop now?