# Convert HH:MM:SS to seconds in momentjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs

I have a string with `12` hour formatted time only

`var time="12:10:12: PM"`

I want to convert this string to seconds.

how can i do this in `moment.js`?

Comment: What do you mean by convert to seconds? Show only the seconds part, or convert to total seconds since some starting period?

Comment: I want to convert the all parts

Comment: Convert to what? You can't convert a single time to seconds. You need a start point and end point (a range) to be able to convert to seconds.
E.g. unix time converts whatever date/time you have to seconds since Jan 1 1970.

Comment: Do you want 12 hours, 10 minutes and 12 seconds as seconds? You mean would desired result be 43200 seconds + 600 seconds + 12 seconds = 43812 seconds?

Comment: You can do it using JavaScript's getTime function see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830244/get-current-date-time-in-seconds

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
moment('12:10:12: PM', 'HH:mm:ss: A').diff(moment().startOf('day'), 'seconds');
```

returns 43812

Comment: Which version are you using to do this? As if moment.js 2.16.0 it does not accept a string format like you've suggested - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/

Comment: Answer has been updated according to moment.js 2.1.0

Comment: @Joao The answer does not work. Are you saying it only works on 2.1.0?

Comment: @daveycroqet Answer has been updated to work in the current version of moment.js, which is 2.19.1

Comment: @TravisCollins It might have been a better idea to leave the original accepted answer with the version it related to, then adding the new answer too with version number, not everyone can up their version easily if they have legacy code etc

Answer (score 43):

I was just trying to achieve the same thing. using 
https://momentjs.com/

This is how I got what I wanted (03:11:23 => 11483 seconds)

```
myVar = moment.duration(myVar).asSeconds()
```

Answer (score 4):

**For mm:ss to seconds**

```
myVar = moment.duration(`00:${'02:00'}`).asSeconds()//mm:ss to seconds
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your first answer. Please try to format your code properly next time! :)