# javascript function getCurTime();

Tags: javascript

this is part of a javascript file i have

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    if(!allowCountdown)return;
    var time = $('.time').text();
    time = time.slice(0,time.length-1);

    if(time > 0) {
        time -= .052;
        time = Math.floor(time * 1000) / 1000;
        if(time < 0)
            time = 0;
        time = time.toFixed(3);
        $('.time').text(time+'s');
    }
    else {

        //getCurTime();
    }
}, 52);
```

It says that the function getCurTime(); is not vaild, 
do you have any idea why is it happening?

Comment: No such function exists. Look at [get current date time in seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830244/get-current-date-time-in-seconds) for some answers.

Comment: What makes you think that `getCurTime()` *should* be a valid function?

Comment: So , what i need to do instead is Date.now()?

Comment: @Juhana to be honest , i didn't write this part of code and im starting programmer so im trying to understand why is the issue happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you wanna get the current time. But, there doesn't exist a function called `getCurTime();`. To get the current time, this is what you should do :

```
var foo=new Date(),
    time= foo.getTime();
```

Check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) to format the time.

Comment: If there is alredy var d exist in the code i need to write something else right?

Comment: Just change the variable name. I'll edit the answer.