# JavaScript Date.getUTCMilliSeconds() not works

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My question is very simple... Consider the following [Angular App](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oimdyr) 
simply create a new date and print the number of UTC milliseconds of that date in the console. My question is why is it zero?

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830244/get-current-date-time-in-seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `getUTCSeconds` is the *seconds* portion of the time. In your case its `0`.

Docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCSeconds

Examples:

```
new Date('July 20, 1969, 20:18:04 UTC'); // 4 
new Date('July 20, 1969, 20:18:00 UTC'); // 0
```

It is *not* the total number of seconds since epoch (which is what you might be thinking)

Comment: @FerchsC you have to use `date.getTime()` for that

Comment: Ok...how i get the total number of seconds since epoch from date in UTC time?