# Timestamp to date format and reverse

Tags: javascript, firebase, date, format, milliseconds

**Hello Guys!**

I just wrote some code with *JavaScript* and *Firebase*, I obtained the date from Firebase in milliseconds and converted it to date format with this code.

```
const dateObject = new Date(milliseconds)

const humanDateFormat = dateObject.toLocaleString("en-US", {day: "numeric"}) + '/' + dateObject.toLocaleString("en-US", {month: "numeric"})  + '/' + dateObject.toLocaleString("en-US", {year: "numeric"});
```

Now I cant find the way back with this kind of date format I used. I want to edit the product but when I try to convert this date I can´t find a useful method.

Maybe should I use LocalStorage to storage the date in milliseconds then search for it and use it?

Thanks anticipated!

Regards, Gaspar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830244/get-current-date-time-in-seconds I think thats what you are searching for.(?)

Comment: Which format do you want the string in? You can try `toISOString()`, `toString()` methods on `dateObject` if they satisfy the need.

Comment: You are likely best to store the original value. However converting a timestamp in d/m/y format is not difficult: `let [d, m, y] = date.split(/\D/); new Date(y, m-1, d).getTime()` will return the time value for that date.