# how to give a div tag a unique id using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, unique, innerhtml, createelement

I'm able to make a div tag using the document.createElement('div')

However i do not know how to give it a unique id.

can anyone help me with this.

I know how to do it using innerHTML however it very cumbersome. (I heard it not a good way of creating a layout.)

Comment: Is the focus here on *unique* as in a random-generated number, or how to cleanly assign an id to the `div` without going into innerHTML as you mentioned?

Comment: Did none of these answers help you? If one did, click the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Understanding `unique` as an ID that must not get mixed up with any other ID's in the markup, the easiest way to go is to get the local timestamp. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript/221297#221297):

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
// With old JS syntax
div.id = "div_" + new Date().getTime().toString();
// With ES6 Template Strings you can also write
div.id = `div_ ${new Date().getTime().toString()}`;
```

Though working with `createElement` can be a bit of a troublemaker, you should be using some JavaScript framework that solve the tiny little details for you (such as jQuery, Mootools, Dojo, etc.).

Comment: I like this test, but I'm worried it's not quite good enough. When I run this back to back, I get two values that are identical. In my "live" test, I got ~6ms differnce in some cases, which is rather close.

Comment: This might be overkill, but I'm using this:
`var datestr = new Date().getTime().toString(),
    randomstr = Math.random().toString();
return string + '_' + MD5(datestr + randomstr);`
MD5 is a function from webtoolkit: http://www.webtoolkit.info/djs/webtoolkit.md5.js

Answer (score 4):

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.id = 'myElementId';
d.innerHTML = 'This is the content!';
```

Or

```
var d = document.createElement('div')
   .id = 'myElementId';
```

.. same thing really, just a different way of laying it out.

This takes care of assigning the id. Now, for unique.  The best way is to use the current time, as it isn't likely to repeat since javascript time is on miliseconds.

Putting it together:

```
var d = document.createElement('div')
   .id = 'id'+new Date().getTime().toString();
```

This does have the chance to duplicate itself in the right circumstances. If it is is hyper-critical to maintain uniqueness, then the only way is to use a pointer:

```
// establish  a variable to hold the pointer
var uniquePointer = 0;

// every time you use the pointer to create a new element, increment the pointer.
var d = document.createElement('div')
   .id = 'id'+uniquePointer;
uniquePointer ++;
```

Comment: I'll remove it now you've updated your answer, but it was a completely valid downvote and should be take as constructive criticism

Comment: I'll take it how I want to, and we now have a generation-spanning blood feud. I shall commence indoctrinating my children within the hour; prepare yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library for this:
https://github.com/LiosK/UUID.js

It "Generates RFC 4122 compliant UUIDs."

Having the element you can assign it the id using the code:

```
element.id = "somePrefix" + UUID.generate()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.id = "myUniqueId";
```

Comment: @adam: Changed it. How's that?

Comment: I've removed the downvote, but I think the question is more about how to generate a unique ID

Comment: @adam: Thanks, bro. I'm ok with you thinking that way. :)

Comment: No, @adam... stick to your guns! This is not a complete answer. "unique" means "not repeated", "different from others". If this code were used twice on the same page... not unique.

Comment: Sound the war drums, internet is serious business. (I've got a fiver that OP doesn't accept any answers anyway...)

Comment: @Chris: ...and it appears you would win that bet.

Comment: @isaaclw, just a bit o' levity between Chris and me.