# Read more opens 1st one all the time

Tags: javascript

I've a page with about 10 short articles.

Each of them as a "Read More" button which when pressed displays hidden text

The issues I have at the moment is when I press the "Read More" on any of the 10 button it shows the 1st articles hidden content and not the selected one.

I think I need to set a unique ID to each article.. and the read more button be linked to it.. But I don't know how to set it.

I looked at this but couldn't get it working [how to give a div tag a unique id using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407067/how-to-give-a-div-tag-a-unique-id-using-javascript)

```
var WidgetContentHideDisplay = {

init:function() {
   if ($('#content-display-hide').size() == 0) return;
    $('.triggerable').click(function(e){
        var element_id = $(this).attr('rel');
        var element = $('#'+element_id);
        element.toggle();
        if (element.is(':visible')) {
            $('.readmore').hide();
        } else {
            $('.readmore').show();
        }
       return false;
   });
}

}

var div = documentElemnt("div");
div.id = "div_" + new Date().gettime().toString;

$(document).ready(function(){ WidgetContentHideDisplay.init(); });
```

*OP Edit: Sorry, the original code wasn't in caps.  I kept getting errors when trying to post, so I copied the code into Dreamweaver and it made it all caps for some reason.*

Comment: What's with all the caps? Please fix that.

Comment: Is your caps-lock key broken and stuck on?  For the sake of everyone on SO, I've reformatted your code.  In the future, for the sake of future coworkers and question-answerers, please use a more readable coding style.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting the element to toggle with an ID (i.e. `$('#'+ELEMENT_ID)`) you could setup a class for your item and use the class selection (e.g. `$('.DETAILED-ARTICLE)'`) to select the child (or the brother, etc. depending how you built the HTML page).

In theory each ID should point to a single element but each class can be put to as many elements as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting errors, read the errors and see what they are.  Off of a quick read of your code, here are a couple things I noticed that will probably cause issues:

- "documentElemnt" is misspelled, which will render it useless.  Also, documentElement is a [read-only property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement), not a function like you're using it.
- toString is a function, not a property, without the parentheses (`.toString()`) it isn't going to function like you want it to.

Run the code, look at the errors in the console, and fix them.  That's where you start.